# What are "res" and "req" parameters in Express functions?

Tags: node.js, express

In the following Express function:

```
app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res){
    res.send('user' + req.params.id);
});
```

What are `req` and `res`? What do they stand for, what do they mean, and what do they do?

Thanks!

Comment: `req` == `"request"` // `res` == `"response"`

Comment: I also wanted to add up my opinion, we should prefer to use params name as request/response instead of req/res as there is only character difference, which may become the cause of the bug, once our codebase increases. Thanks.

Answer (score 321, accepted):

`req` is an object containing information about the HTTP request that raised the event.  In response to `req`, you use `res` to send back the desired HTTP response.

Those parameters can be named anything.  You could change that code to this if it's more clear:

```
app.get('/user/:id', function(request, response){
  response.send('user ' + request.params.id);
});
```

Edit:

Say you have this method:

```
app.get('/people.json', function(request, response) { });
```

The request will be an object with properties like these (just to name a few):

- `request.url`, which will be `"/people.json"` when this particular action is triggered
- `request.method`, which will be `"GET"` in this case, hence the `app.get()` call.
- An array of HTTP headers in `request.headers`, containing items like `request.headers.accept`, which you can use to determine what kind of browser made the request, what sort of responses it can handle, whether or not it's able to understand HTTP compression, etc.
- An array of query string parameters if there were any, in `request.query` (e.g. `/people.json?foo=bar` would result in `request.query.foo` containing the string `"bar"`).

To respond to that request, you use the response object to build your response.  To expand on the `people.json` example:

```
app.get('/people.json', function(request, response) {
  // We want to set the content-type header so that the browser understands
  //  the content of the response.
  response.contentType('application/json');

  // Normally, the data is fetched from a database, but we can cheat:
  var people = [
    { name: 'Dave', location: 'Atlanta' },
    { name: 'Santa Claus', location: 'North Pole' },
    { name: 'Man in the Moon', location: 'The Moon' }
  ];

  // Since the request is for a JSON representation of the people, we
  //  should JSON serialize them. The built-in JSON.stringify() function
  //  does that.
  var peopleJSON = JSON.stringify(people);

  // Now, we can use the response object's send method to push that string
  //  of people JSON back to the browser in response to this request:
  response.send(peopleJSON);
});
```

Comment: you can use curl to see the response complete with headers

Comment: You might want to check out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol. Not being snarky, that's something all of us who develop for the Web need to know about!

Comment: Yes this was great should be on main page of the express.js website.

Comment: expressnoob - response is an object, just like the request object is, but it contains fields and methods pertaining to the response.  Normally the response's send() method is used.  send() accepts a whole bunch of different types for the first argument, which becomes the HTTP response body, and the second argument is the HTTP response code.

Comment: If someone is looking for details of `req` and `res` structure, it is described in express docs: `req`:http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req, `res`: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res

Comment: OK, so the server ("app") has received a GET request for "/people.json". The request argument contains lots of useful details about that request, and the response argument allows you to choose what to send back in your reply. Neat. Thanks.

Comment: When I  `console.log(request.params)` it prints out `undefined`

Comment: @Anton The [express.js.com website](https://expressjs.com/) has some example [response methods](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#response-methods) to illustrate this further.

Comment: Are req and res exclusive to expressjs or are these the NodeJs Request and Response objects?

Answer (score 26):

I noticed one error in Dave Ward's answer (perhaps a recent change?):
The query string paramaters are in `request.query`, not `request.params`. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6913287/166530 )

`request.params` by default is filled with the value of any "component matches" in routes, i.e.

```
app.get('/user/:id', function(request, response){
  response.send('user ' + request.params.id);
});
```

and, if you have configured express to use its bodyparser (`app.use(express.bodyParser());`) also with POST'ed formdata. (See [How to retrieve POST query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-get-post-query-in-express-node-js) )

Answer (score 7):

Request and response.

To understand the `req`, try out `console.log(req);`.

Comment: This doesn't help; the output in the console is [object Object].

Comment: If you want json, you have to: 
console.log(JSON.Stringify(req.body);