# How to access POST form fields in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express

Here is my simple form:

```html
<form id="loginformA" action="userlogin" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email: </label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email"></input>
    </div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

Here is my [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js)/Node.js code:

```
app.post('/userlogin', function(sReq, sRes){    
    var email = sReq.query.email.;   
}
```

I tried `sReq.query.email` or `sReq.query['email']` or `sReq.params['email']`, etc. None of them work. They all return `undefined`.

When I change to a Get call, it works, so .. any idea?

Comment: **SECURITY**: everybody using `bodyParser()` from answers here should also read [@SeanLynch 's answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20132867/137626)

Answer (score 1405, accepted):

Things have [changed](https://expressjs.com/en/changelog/4x.html#4.16.0) once again starting **Express 4.16.0**, you can now use `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded()` just like in **Express 3.0**.

This was [different](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware) starting **Express 4.0 to 4.15**:

```
$ npm install --save body-parser
```

and then:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));
```

The rest is like in **Express 3.0**:

Firstly you need to add some middleware to parse the post data of the body.

Add one or both of the following lines of code:

```
app.use(express.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded()); // to support URL-encoded bodies
```

Then, in your handler, use the [`req.body`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body) object:

```
// assuming POST: name=foo&color=red            <-- URL encoding
//
// or       POST: {"name":"foo","color":"red"}  <-- JSON encoding

app.post('/test-page', function(req, res) {
    var name = req.body.name,
        color = req.body.color;
    // ...
});
```

---

Note that the use of [`express.bodyParser()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#bodyParser) is not recommended.

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

...is equivalent to:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.multipart());
```

Security concerns exist with `express.multipart()`, and so it is better to explicitly add support for the specific encoding type(s) you require. If you do need multipart encoding (to support uploading files for example) then you should [read this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/express-js/iP2VyhkypHo/5AXQiYN3RPcJ).

Comment: If this answer isn't working right, make sure you have the `content-type` header set, for example: `curl -d '{"good_food":["pizza"]}' -H 'content-type:application/json'  "http://www.example.com/your_endpoint"`

Comment: what is the difference between posting a form with name/value pairs and posting a JSON body? Do they both show up in req.body?

Comment: @chovy Yes, they do. `bodyParser` abstracts JSON, URL-encoded and multipart data into the `req.body` object.

Comment: express.json() etc. are part of connect, not express, so, middlewars are should be referenced by connect.middelwarename instead of express.middleware

Comment: This code gave me errors as middleware is no longer bundled with Express; you'll have to use body-parser: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware

Comment: `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` works without error

Comment: For reading json using Express 4, only the `app.use(require('body-parser').json())` line is sufficient. And then you can read the json data from your request's body object, i.e. `req.body`, from within a route definition.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why `JSON.parse('{'+params.split('=')
 .join(':') .split('&') .join(',')+'}');` needed to be its own separate middleware component rather than something Express.js just does out of the box. How is sifting through now dozens of dependencies to make the simplest things happen any easier than just using http.listen?

Comment: You're already telling express what to use. Omit the following and it'll work just fine.

    app.use(express.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
    app.use(express.urlencoded()); // to support URL-encoded bodies

Comment: can i change the data type at this point. i am using strongloop and I want to change the the incoming string to number ? How to do that ?

Answer (score 108):

**Security concern using express.bodyParser()**

While all the other answers currently recommend using the `express.bodyParser()` middleware, this is actually a wrapper around the `express.json()`, `express.urlencoded()`, and `express.multipart()` middlewares (http://expressjs.com/api.html#bodyParser).  The parsing of form request bodies is done by the `express.urlencoded()` middleware and is all that you need to expose your form data on `req.body` object.

Due to a [security concern](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/express-js/iP2VyhkypHo/5AXQiYN3RPcJ) with how `express.multipart()`/`connect.multipart()` creates temporary files for all uploaded files (and are not garbage collected), it is now *[recommended](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0)* not to use the `express.bodyParser()` wrapper but instead use only the middlewares you need.

Note: `connect.bodyParser()` will soon be updated to only include `urlencoded` and `json` when Connect 3.0 is released (which Express extends).

---

So in short, instead of ...

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

...you should use

```
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());      // if needed
```

and if/when you need to handle multipart forms (file uploads), use a third party library or middleware such as multiparty, busboy, dicer, etc.

Comment: Added a comment below question so more people see your concerns and advice. Would other solutions detailed in [Andrew Kelley blog post](http://andrewkelley.me/post/do-not-use-bodyparser-with-express-js.html) (still) relevant in your opinion? (just asking for others, my needs are purely for internal tools ^^)

Comment: @FelipeAls - Yes, and I meant to reference Andrew's post as well.  Any of those suggestions (taking into consideration the downfalls of each) are relevant.

Comment: Also, once Connect 3.0 is released without including `multipart()` as part of `bodyParser()`, `bodyParser()` becomes "safe" again, but you will need to explicitly enable multipart support using a third party library.

Answer (score 88):

**Note**: this answer is for Express 2. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12008719/21115) for Express 3.

If you're using connect/express, you should use the [bodyParser middleware](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js): It's described in the [Expressjs guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html).

```
// example using express.js:
var express = require('express')
  , app = express.createServer();
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.post('/', function(req, res){
  var email = req.param('email', null);  // second parameter is default
});
```

Here's the original connect-only version:

```
// example using just connect
var connect = require('connect');
var url = require('url');
var qs = require('qs');
var server = connect(
  connect.bodyParser(),
  connect.router(function(app) {
    app.post('/userlogin', function(req, res) {
      // the bodyParser puts the parsed request in req.body.
      var parsedUrl = qs.parse(url.parse(req.url).query);
      var email = parsedUrl.email || req.body.email;;
    });
  })
);
```

Both the querystring and body are parsed using [Rails-style parameter handling (`qs`)](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-querystring) rather than the [low-level `querystring` library](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.6/api/querystring.html). In order to parse repeated parameters with `qs`, the parameter needs to have brackets: `name[]=val1&name[]=val2`. It also supports nested maps. In addition to parsing HTML form submissions, the bodyParser can parse JSON requests automatically.

**Edit**: I read up on express.js and modified my answer to be more natural to users of Express.

Comment: Hmm ok. i try the bodyParser().  the doc says i can get it from req.query() but i got nothing. that's very weird.   I have no problem with Get tho.

Comment: No, req.query is ONLY the GET params. You get the POST data through req.body. The function req.params() includes them both.

Answer (score 42):

This will do it if you want to build the posted query without middleware:

```
app.post("/register/",function(req,res){
    var bodyStr = '';
    req.on("data",function(chunk){
        bodyStr += chunk.toString();
    });
    req.on("end",function(){
        res.send(bodyStr);
    });

});
```

That will send this to the browser

```
email=emailval&password1=pass1val&password2=pass2val
```

It's probably better to use middleware though so you don't have to write this over and over in each route.

Comment: sooo.... handy, for those that don't want to rely on a library that will sooner or later be deprecated

Comment: you could easily build your own middleware

Comment: This is a great answer but why there is extra text "----------------------------359856253150893337905494
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fullName"

Ram
----------------------------359856253150893337905494--" I don't want that number.

Answer (score 29):

**Note for Express 4 users:**

If you try and put `app.use(express.bodyParser());` into your app, you'll get the following error when you try to start your Express server:

> Error: Most middleware (like bodyParser) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.

You'll have to install the package `body-parser` separately [from npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser), then use something like the following (example taken from [the GitHub page](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)):

```
var express    = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body) // populated!
  next();
})
```

Comment: heplp: body-parser deprecated bodyParser: use individual json/urlencoded middlewares

Answer (score 24):

Given some form:

```
<form action='/somepath' method='post'>
   <input type='text' name='name'></input>
</form>
```

Using express

```
app.post('/somepath', function(req, res) {

    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));

    console.log('req.body.name', req.body['name']);
});
```

Output:

```
{"name":"x","description":"x"}
req.param.name x
```

Comment: didnt work for me. need to use app.use(express.bodyParser());

Comment: @cawecoy absolutely right same here but express.bodyParser() not working as well for me it deprecated

Comment: @MohammadFaizankhan it was an experimental work, I didn't use express anymore, can't help now. Google it for similar functions to express.bodyParser(). good lucky!

Comment: This works only if you are using body-parser

Answer (score 21):

Backend:

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // add a middleware (so that express can parse request.body's json)

app.post('/api/courses', (request, response) => {
  response.json(request.body);
});
```

Frontend:

```
fetch("/api/courses", {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({ hi: 'hello' }), // convert Js object to a string
  headers: new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" }) // add headers
});
```

Answer (score 16):

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Then for `app.post` request you can get post values via `req.body.{post request variable}`.

Comment: your post request variable here, is that the id of the input field in question or the whole form or what?

Comment: express.bodyParser() is deprecated. update your answer

Answer (score 15):

### Update for Express 4.4.1

Middleware of the following is removed from Express.

- bodyParser
- json
- urlencoded
- multipart

When you use the middleware directly like you did in express 3.0. You will get the following error:

```
Error: Most middleware (like urlencoded) is no longer bundled with Express and 
must be installed separately.
```

In order to utilize those middleware, now you need to do **npm** for each middleware separately.

Since bodyParser is marked as deprecated, so I recommend the following way using json, urlencode and multipart parser like formidable, connect-multiparty. (Multipart middleware is deprecated as well).

**Also remember, just defining urlencode + json, the form data will not be parsed and req.body will be undefined. You need to define a middleware handle the multipart request.**

```
var urlencode = require('urlencode');
var json = require('json-middleware');
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartMiddleware = multipart();

app.use(json);
app.use(urlencode);
app.use('/url/that/accepts/form-data', multipartMiddleware);
```

Comment: i guess this is really bad feature updation

Comment: just for the sake of body parse i have to do lots of code. what the hack is

Comment: I had to add ".middleware()" to require('json-middleware') to get this to work.

Answer (score 12):

**Update**

As of `Express version 4.16+`, their own body-parser implementation is now included in the default Express package so there is no need for you to download another dependency.

You may have added a line to your code that looks like the following:

```
app.use(bodyparser.json()); //utilizes the body-parser package
```

If you are using Express 4.16+ you can now replace that line with:

```
app.use(express.json()); //Used to parse JSON bodies
```

This should not introduce any breaking changes into your applications since the code in express.json() is based on bodyparser.json().

If you also have the following code in your environment:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

You can replace that with:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded()); //Parse URL-encoded bodies
```

A final note of caution: There are still some very specific cases where `body-parser` might still be necessary but for the most part `Express`’ implementation of body-parser is all you will need for the majority of use cases.

(See the docs at [expressjs/bodyparser](http://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) for more details).

Answer (score 9):

I was searching for this exact problem. I was following all the advice above but req.body was still returning an empty object {}. In my case, it was something just as simple as the html being incorrect.

In your form's html, make sure you use the `'name'` attribute in your input tags, not just `'id'`. Otherwise, nothing is parsed.

```
<input id='foo' type='text' value='1'/>             // req = {}
<input id='foo' type='text' name='foo' value='1' /> // req = {foo:1}
```

My idiot mistake is your benefit.

Comment: Same problem here. But I was using the name attribute from the start. Let's see what the problem is.

Answer (score 8):

You shoudn't use **app.use(express.bodyParser())**. BodyParser is a union of json + urlencoded + mulitpart. You shoudn't use this because multipart will be removed in connect 3.0.

To resolve that, you can do this:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

It´s very important know that **app.use(app.router)** should be used after the json and urlencoded, otherwise it does not work!

Answer (score 8):

## For Express 4.1 and above

As most of the answers are using to Express, bodyParser, connect; where multipart is deprecated. There is a secure way to send post multipart objects easily.

Multer can be used as replacement for connect.multipart().

To install the package

```
$ npm install multer
```

Load it in your app:

```
var multer = require('multer');
```

And then, add it in the middleware stack along with the other form parsing middleware.

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/' }));
```

**connect.json()** handles application/json

**connect.urlencoded()** handles application/x-www-form-urlencoded

**multer()** handles multipart/form-data

Answer (score 8):

**Express v4.17.0**

```
app.use(express.urlencoded( {extended: true} ))

app.post('/userlogin', (req, res) => {    

   console.log(req.body) // object

   var email = req.body.email;

}
```

[express.urlencoded](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html)

[Demo Form](https://1v53n.sse.codesandbox.io/)

[Another Answer Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-to-process-post-data-in-node-js/58072865#58072865)

Comment: what is the purpose of setting extended to true? what does that mean?

Comment: This option allows to choose between parsing the URL-encoded data with the querystring library (when false) or the qs library (when true). The “extended” syntax allows for rich objects and arrays to be encoded into the URL-encoded format, allowing for a JSON-like experience with URL-encoded.

Answer (score 6):

**Written at Express version 4.16**

Inside the router function you can use `req.body` property to access the post variable. For example if this was the `POST` route of your form, it would send back what you input:

```
function(req,res){
      res.send(req.body);

      //req.body.email would correspond with the HTML <input name="email"/>
}
```

P.S. for those who are familiar with PHP: In order to access PHP's `$_GET` variable we use `req.query` and to access PHP's `$_POST` variable we use `req.body` in Node.js.

Answer (score 5):

Request streaming worked for me

```
req.on('end', function() {
    var paramstring = postdata.split("&");
});

var postdata = "";
req.on('data', function(postdataChunk){
    postdata += postdataChunk;
});
```

Comment: Better than doing `postdata.split("&")` would be to load core module `querystring = require('querystring')` and then parse your `postdata` with `querystring.parse(postdata)`;

Answer (score 4):

I could find all parameters by using following code for both **POST** and **GET** requests.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const util = require('util');
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Got a POST request for the homepage");
    res.send(util.inspect(req.query,false,null));
})
```

Comment: do you mind updating the answer with your version of express?

Answer (score 3):

*Other answers talk about the middleware to use on the server side. My answer attempt to provide developers with a simple playbook to debug the problem themselves.*

---

In this question, the situation is:

- You have a **form** on the client side
- The data is sent by clicking on Submit button and you don't use JavaScript to send requests (so no `fetch`, `axios`, `xhr`,... but we can extend the solution for these cases later)
- You use **Express** for the server side
- You **cannot access data** in your Express code. `req.body` is `undefined`

There are some actions that you can do to find the solution by yourself:

1. Open the **Network** tab and search for your request.
2. Check the **request header `Content-Type`**. In this situation (form submit), the header is likely `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` if you send a file (with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form tag)
3. Now check your Express code if you use the **appropriate middleware** to parse incoming requests.

- If your Content-Type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then you should have `app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))` in your code.
- If your Content-Type is `multipart/form-data`: because Express doesn't have a built-in middleware to parse this kind of request, you should another library for that. `multer` is a good one.

4. If you have done all the steps above, now you can access data in `req.body` :). If you have problems with the syntax, you should check the [Express document page](https://expressjs.com/). The syntax could be changed because this question is posted a long time ago.

Now, we can extend this simple playbook for other cases that involve JavaScript code. The key is to check the request Content-Type. If you see `application/json` then you should use `app.use(express.json())` in your code.

**In summary, find your request Content-Type, then use the appropriate middleware to parse it**.

Answer (score 2):

from [official](https://expressjs.com/ru/4x/api.html#req) doc version 4

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })) 

app.post('/push/send', (request, response) => {
  console.log(request.body)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Post Parameters can be retrieved as follows:

```
app.post('/api/v1/test',Testfunction);
http.createServer(app).listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + port)
});

function Testfunction(request,response,next) {
   console.log(request.param("val1"));
   response.send('HI');
}
```

Comment: do you realize this won't work ? `param` is used for GET requests.. not POST and your example lacks of details, very confusing for new comers. And on top of that `request.param` is actually deprecated, so your example is wrong on so many levels.

Answer (score 1):

Use **express-fileupload** package:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')

app.use(fileUpload());

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  var email = req.body.email;
  res.send('<h1>Email :</h1> '+email);
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Running Port:3000');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var express        =         require("express");
var bodyParser     =         require("body-parser");
var app            =         express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendfile("index.html");
});
app.post('/login',function(req,res){
  var user_name=req.body.user;
  var password=req.body.password;
  console.log("User name = "+user_name+", password is "+password);
  res.end("yes");
});
app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("Started on PORT 3000");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `req.query.post` with wrong method `req.query.post` works with `method=get`, `method=post` works with **body-parser**.

Just try this by changing **post** to **get** :

```
<form id="loginformA" action="userlogin" method="get">
<div>
    <label for="email">Email: </label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email"></input>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>  
</form>
```

And in express code use 'app.get'

Comment: There are a number of reasons to use `POST` instead of `GET`-  security and data size are right out in front - so this is not an apt approach.

Answer (score -2):

when you are using POST method in HTML forms, you need to catch the data from req.body in the server side i.e. Node.js.
and also add

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use( bodyParser.json() );    
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

**OR**

use method='GET' in HTML and and catch the data by req.query in the server side i.e. Node.js