# Posting Jquery Data to Express

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, express

No matter what combination of req.params/req.query/req.body and $.post({..} I use, I am unable to extract JSON data from my Jquery post request in express.

This is my **jQuery**:

```
$.post("/mail", {email : "s@gmail.com", name : "s@gmail.com"});
```

I have also tried various permutations of:

```
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: "/mail", dataType :"json", data :
{email : "s@gmail.com", name : "s@gmail.com"}});
```

This is my node.js **express** code:

```
app.post("/mail", function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.body.name);
   console.log(req.route);
   console.log("params1: " + req.param.params);
....
```

I have tried endless ways of accessing the data email and name without success. I'd be surprised if the solution were a simple modification to req.body/ req.params but anything is possible! The data just ain't there! (It does not appear in my url either -- all I see is localhost:1337)

req.body / req.params / req.param.params / req.params *all  return* **undefined** and req.query *returns* **[]**.

req.route *returns*:

```
{ path: '/mail',
  method: 'post',
  callbacks: [ [Function] ],
  keys: [],
  regexp: /^\/mail\/?$/i,
  params: [] }
```

I've tried adding:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

But, admittedly, I do not fully understand its purpose. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Happy holidays!
// Sam

Comment: Maybe this will help you a bit? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-get-post-query-in-express-node-js

Comment: The `bodyParser` middleware is the one initializing `req.body` from the POST body, so you really need that. Make sure you use it before you mount your routes (i.e. before you either do `app.use(app.router)` or your first `app.get`/`app.post` etc call).

Comment: What Linus said, make sure in your configuration bodyParser is set BEFORE your routing.

Comment: What do you know! That fixed it. `app.use(express.bodyParser());` just had to come before the first app.get/post . Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add the [`bodyParser()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#bodyParser) middleware before any routes that use it, like so:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/mail', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body); // the body attribute will be created by the bodyParser()
});
```

The way express works is that each request is trickled down through your middleware and routes in the order that they're declared. Since the `bodyParser()` middleware is now declared before your route, it'll have a chance to parse the body of the request into a nice JSON format, stick that parsed value into [`req.body`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body), and then pass on control to the next route/middleware; otherwise, `req.body` will simply not exists.