# node.js jquery - .post ajax like php

Tags: node.js

I am coming from `PHP` where an `AJAX` call from `jQuery` is done like this. 
html:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var mydata = 'abc123';
    $.post( 'process.php', { mydata:mydata}, function(data){
            $('body').append('<h1>'+data+'</h1>');
        });
    return false;
});
```

php:

```
$post = $_POST['mydata'];
echo $post;
```

**Question:** how can i replace the `PHP` part with `node.js` to do the same thing? 
also i would need to change this part of `jQuery` `$.post( 'process.php', ...` 
would that look like this? `$.post( 'process.js', ...`?

[I saw this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/http-post-request-in-node-js) but i couldnt translate it from php to node

This helped out, from "Node.js for PHP developers"

> In PHP, a PHP file represents an HTML page. A web server, such as Apache, accepts
>   requests and if a PHP page is requested, the web server runs the PHP. But in Node.js,
>   the main Node.js file represents the entire web server. It does not run inside a web server
>   like Apache; it replaces Apache.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you extract POST data in node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js)

Comment: (includes some good links, like http://blog.frankgrimm.net/2010/11/howto-access-http-message-body-post-data-in-node-js/ and http://jnjnjn.com/113/node-js-for-noobs-grabbing-post-content/). If you're using express, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-get-post-query-in-express-node-js

Comment: @BrandonTilley thanks! will look into the links