# How do I get query string from a POST?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, query-string

I'm using `node.js 0.10.22` and `express 3.4.6`

I would like to send something like this `/upload?slides=2` and then get the value for `slides`

I'm using the `bodyParser` middleware.

I have this:

```
app.get('/',function(req, res) {
    // show a file upload form
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(
        '<form action="/upload?slides=2" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">'+
        '<input type="text" name="title"><br>'+
        '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>'+
        '<input type="submit" value="Upload">'+
        '</form>'
    );
});

app.post('/upload',function(req,res){
    doLog("/upload","hit upload");
    //console.log(req);
    console.log("params = ");
    console.log(req.body);
    ...
```

In the console I just get `{title: ''}`

Or do I have to put the parameters elsewhere in the form?

Comment: try `console.dir(req)` in the app.post()

Comment: @rdodev that didn't change anything.

Comment: So what is `slides`, there are no elements with that name? Are you trying to get the files ?

Comment: @Houseman of course that doesn't change anything functionally, but it should output of the req structure, which is what you want to see.

Comment: @adeneo no, I'm not trying to get the files. I'm trying to send extra information not contained in the files I want to upload

Comment: Then add hidden form fields, you're not doing a GET request, but a POST request, you can't just add stuff to the querystring.

Comment: @rdodev I meant that I still get the same output. But then I realized that I wrote it wrong, and now I get a giant object

Comment: @adeneo Okay, I'll add hidden form fields. I didn't know that I couldn't just add stuff to the querystring

Comment: I think someone else already asked this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-get-post-query-in-express-node-js

Comment: @rdodev I tried the solutions in that answer first. I got it to work using a slightly different method, which I posted as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work after using

`console.dir(req)`. From the output of that, I saw an object called `query` with my parameters inside.

Then I called
`console.log(req.query.slides)` and it returned `2`, which was what I wanted.

Comment: So, basically you used what I suggested in the comments and decided to post an answer by yourself?

Comment: @rdodev You didn't say anything about `req.query`. You only gave me `console.dir`, which I upvoted you for.

  The people who answered the similar question that you linked to didn't say anything about `req.query`  either. In fact, the asker tried using `req.query`, and it wouldn't work for him.

Comment: I suggested you use `console.dir(req)` and you immediately dismissed me saying that "didn't change anything". I had to explain to you that what you want to see is the structure of `req` because that's where your likely answer was, given it wasn't in `req.body`. That's when you saw that `req.query` had the contents you wanted. Failing to recognize that you wouldn't have gotten that far without those tips is your prerogative. Usually in this site when someone helps you, it's good etiquette to have them submit an answer and accept it. Anyhow, your issue is now solved and that's what matters.

Comment: @rdodev I followed that immediate dismissal with `"...I realized that I wrote it wrong, and now I get a giant object"`. I knew I wouldn't have gotten this far without your tip. But that's what it was. A tip. That's why I gave you an upvote. You didn't give me the answer, you only helped me to reach it. If you would have mentioned `req.query`, I would have asked you to make an answer out of it.