# Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. Express

Tags: mysql, node.js

The full code is following - pretty simply i wanna add, delete or update posts - when i do one of the things by them self it works but togther it breaks

Iv'd searched alot in the [**NodeJS MySQL**](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) which i use to query the database

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host : 'localhost',
  port : 3306,
  database: 'nodeproject',
  user : 'noderoot',
  password : 'default'
});

var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var exphbs  = require('express3-handlebars');
var qs = require('querystring');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

configQuery = function() {
  connection.config.queryFormat = function (query, values) {
  if (!values) return query;
  return query.replace(/\:(\w+)/g, function (txt, key) {
    if (values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      return this.escape(values[key]);
    }
    return txt;
  }.bind(this));
  };
}


index = function(req, res){
    /*connection.connect(function(err){
      if(err != null) {
        res.end('Error connecting to mysql:' + err+'\n');
      }
    });*/

    connection.query("SELECT * FROM posts", function(err, rows){
      if(err != null) {
        res.end("Query error:" + err);
      } else {
        var myOuterRows = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var myRows = rows[i];
            myOuterRows.push(myRows);
        };

        res.render('index', { 
            title: 'Express Handlebars Test',
            posts: myOuterRows
        });
      }
    });
};

addpost = function(req, res) {
    var post  = {
        id: req.body.post.id, 
        postTitle: req.body.post.postTitle, 
        postContent: req.body.post.postContent,
        published: req.body.post.published
    };

    connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
        console.log("Neat! you entered a post");
    });

    res.redirect("/");
}
editpost = function(req, res) {

    configQuery();

    var edit = {
        id: req.body.editpost.id, 
        postTitle: req.body.editpost.postTitle, 
        postContent: req.body.editpost.postContent
    };


    var queryTitle = connection.query("UPDATE posts SET ?", edit, function(err, result) {
        console.log("Neat! you editted a post")
    });

    res.redirect("/");
}
deletepost = function(req, res) {

    configQuery();

    var deleteThis  = {
        id: req.body.deletepost.id
    };

    console.log(deleteThis);

    var queryDelete = connection.query("DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = :id", {
        id: deleteThis.id
    });

    res.redirect("/");
}

app.get('/', index);

app.post('/', addpost);
app.post('/', editpost);
app.post('/', deletepost);

//app.get('/list', list);

http.createServer(app).listen(8000, function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));


});
```

The error i get is following:

```
500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
at editpost (C:\dev\ExpressHbsMysql\app.js:96:24)
at callbacks (C:\dev\ExpressHbsMysql\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
at param (C:\dev\ExpressHbsMysql\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)
at pass (C:\dev\ExpressHbsMysql\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5)
at Router._dispatch (C:\dev\ExpressHbsMysql\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:173:5)
at Object.router (C:\dev\ExpressHbsMysql\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10)
at next (C:\dev\ExpressHbsMysql\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (C:\dev\ExpressHbsMysql\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\methodOverride.js:48:5)
at next (C:\dev\ExpressHbsMysql\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
at C:\dev\ExpressHbsMysql\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\urlencoded.js:83:7
```

Comment: i couldn't read much but one thing i notice is why would you map one url to multiple handlers? like `/` with type `post` is mapped to `editpost`, `deletepost`, `addpost`

Comment: Have you tried google's node-debug and put breakpoints at/above the lines of the error and see what objects are there, what objects should be there etc and then trace back where it goes wrong? Oh, and use only one app.VERB() per url and do the conditional workflow in that one function.

Comment: @pronox http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-get-post-query-in-express-node-js id followed this example of how to do post form in node

Comment: @Pengtuzi havn't tried that? got a link?

Comment: @SimonPertersen what i want to say is kindof long as i posted it as an answer check this it might help

Comment: @SimonPertersen yes your code allow should work as you followed that stack question but i mean expose each of your handler at different url .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where should it go?

```
app.post('/', addpost);
app.post('/', editpost);
app.post('/', deletepost);
```

To `addpost` or to `editpost` or to `deletepost`

As far as i can tell from your code i suggest you keep different urls for each handler that way you will tell which handler to call, right now all your post requests call first handler which is `addpost`

Map your handlers like this

```
app.post('/post/add', addpost);
app.post('/post/edit', editpost);
app.post('/post/delete', deletepost);
```

Next in your forms or if your are using ajax post your `addrequest` to '/post/add', `editrequest` to `/post/edit` and so on.

Comment: But what if they are on the same page - does that matter? the url what does it do?

Comment: actually if you are editing then post your form to url with post handler let me update my answer

Comment: Else i would in each form element set the form action to the url?

Comment: @SimonPertersen it does not matter what page is rendering your view all that matters is keep your handlers at the right place. Then send requests to corresponding handler irrespective of the view.

Comment: how are you handling your form action?

Comment: just by a native form element - i got delete and add to work simultaneously i think the addpost have ran into another problem

Comment: @SimonPertersen try using javascript in for posting your forms, so if some is adding a post you'll know where to send request, if someone is clicking delete post button you should then post your request to delete request and the same way you handle your editrequest.

Comment: Ty for help - clean an easy respons