# How do i send data from html to mongodb?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

I am using node js with express and Mongo. I have a simple program that takes in user settings through radio buttons. I have a submit button but I do not know how to make it work from there. Do I need a new JS file to send it to mongodb?  All I want is for my html to save the preferences and store them to the database. What steps do I start going in?

Example here:
if I clicked male and hit submit, I would want the word male to save to the database.

```
<html>
  <body>
      <form action="">
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your server-side code that is handling the POST?  Or... is that what your question is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you want to send a http post to node js.

This will show you how to do that.
[How to retrieve POST query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-get-post-query-in-express-node-js)

Then you need to take that info and parse it and then send it to Mongo.

This will show you how to do an insert using Nodejs Mongo Driver.
http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html

Answer (score 0):

1. create server.
2. send http req.
3. connect to mongodb.
4. insert data in mongodb

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on the http req? Maybe add some code
?