# Can't capture POST params with Node.js and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying a simple [Node.js + Express RESTful API](http://pixelhandler.com/posts/develop-a-restful-api-using-nodejs-with-express-and-mongoose) example, and I've created a simple action to simulate a login request. Here is my code:

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});
module.exports = app;
```

**users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

/* My Login */
router.post('/login', function(req, res){
    var data = {
        user : req.body.user,
        pass : req.body.pass
    };
    res.send(data);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm simulating a POST request with Postman (user = joe, pass = 123456), but I'm receiving an empty `{}` as response. Already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-get-post-query-in-express-node-js), without success. How can I capture POST params on Node.js? What is wrong?

**UPDATED**
I've embed my *app.js* and *users.js* code for a better review.

Comment: That's weird, at the very least you should receive the object with empty values or an error message. Does your NodeJS output any error logs? Are you sure your routing path is working correctly?

Comment: What is the version of Express that you are using? You need to use the bodyParser middleware.

Comment: What middleware do you have set up *before* that router? Can you show that code too?

Comment: @Hless there aren't error messages. The route works fine, I can print a `Hello World`, for example. But `req.body.user` returns an undefined value.

Comment: Also, what does `console.log(req.headers['content-type'])` show?

Comment: @mscdex `console.log(req.headers['content-type'])` shows
`multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryEgVAuaovj7k6ABuR`

Comment: @mscdex Check out my post, I've updated with the *app.js* code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're sending a `multipart/form-data` request but you are not using any middleware that handles those types of requests (`body-parser` in Express 4 only handles `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and JSON requests).

So you'll need to use a multipart parsing module such as [connect-busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy)/[busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy), [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) (Express 3 bodyParser-like API using busboy), [connect-multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/connect-multiparty)/[multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty), [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) (the previously bundled Express 3 bodyParser middleware), or [reformed](https://github.com/mscdex/reformed) (uses busboy).

Comment: I've installed the `body-parser` as decribed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12008719/2684718), but now, I have the following message: `Error: Most middleware (like json) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.`

Comment: Like I mentioned, `body-parser` does not handle multipart, so that will not help you. Although if you're not uploading files, you could use `body-parser` with your `Content-Type` set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` works great to me!