# Is HTTP POST Request blocked (critically altered) by Cloud9?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-post, cloud9-ide

I (try to) run a node.js app on cloud9 (c9.io).
It requires express.

It hosts a html file 
`app.get('/index.html', function(req, res){
      res.sendfile('./client/index.html');
    });`

which includes a form


    `<form action="/myaction" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"...
    <input type="submit" value="Send message" />`

I manage to hit the button, send a HTTP POST request with parameter name="somevalue" - which is prooven by Firebug Network Monitoring.
BUT
when I log the recieved req-object 

    `app.post('/myaction', function(req1, res) {
      //res.send('You sent the name "' + req.body.name + '".');
      res.send("das der req " + req1 + ".");
      console.log(req1);
    });`

it looks like a mess: http://pastebin.com/iq7mfueC - I can't find the name Parameter, because I can't find the form at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get POST query in express node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-get-post-query-in-express-node-js)

Comment: Either listen for `data` events yourself and reconstruct the payload or use the `body-parser` module.

Comment: Thank you very much, Joe. It is indeed a duplicate.