# how to get the values from postman extention "form-data" values

Tags: node.js

I am using node js with express framework and rest api
for rest api client i am using postman extension with chrome browser
here i am able to get values from option "x-www-form-urlencoded" but i am not able to get values from "form data" i want to get values from "form data" option and also need to upload image file.
please help me any to achieve this. i want to get values from "form data" option and also image. please help me.
Below i have mentioned code what i have used.
[image]

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var mysql = require('mysql');
var util = require('util');
var trim = require('trim');
var validator = require('validator');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Ingest      = require('ingest');
var multer      = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
var type = upload.single('recfile');
 passport = require('passport')
 , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

async = require('async');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 
   extended: true 
}));

app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.file); // "form-data" values not able to get here
    console.log(req);// "form-data" values not able to get here
    console.log('body : '+JSON.stringify(req.body));// "form-data"  values not able to get here
});
```

i didn't set any content type in postman header

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
    console.log('req.headers \n '+JSON.stringify(req.headers));     
    console.log('req.body.file :- '+req.body.file);
    console.log('\n\n req.body :- '+JSON.stringify(req.body));
});
```

I got the below result for the above code.
req.headers

```
 {"host":"localhost:3001","connection":"keep-alive","content length":"5808","cache-control":"no-cache","origin":"chrome-extension://mkhojklkhkdaghjjfdnphfphiaiohkef","password":"password","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36","username":"User2","content-type":"multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryV4zAIbjEyKYxLRWe","accept":"*/*","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.8","cookie":"connect.sid=s%3Atz4f1ZgJkaAjuDD1sOkMB9rr.Z8EUIyxEcr0EyFQL96v0ExGRidM3SAVTx8IIr52O0OI"}
```

req.body.file :- undefined

req.body :- {}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got solution with help of the below code

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var util = require("util"); 
    var fs = require("fs");
    var formidable = require('formidable');
    var path = require('path');

    router.post("/upload", function(req, res, next){ 
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        // `file` is the name of the <input> field of type `file`
        console.log(files);
        console.log(fields);
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write('received upload:\n\n');
        res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });
    form.on('error', function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
    form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
        var percent_complete = (bytesReceived / bytesExpected) * 100;
        console.log(percent_complete.toFixed(2));
    });
    form.on('end', function(fields, files) {
        /* Temporary location of our uploaded file */
        var temp_path = this.openedFiles[0].path;
        /* The file name of the uploaded file */
        var file_name = this.openedFiles[0].name;
        /* Location where we want to copy the uploaded file */
        var new_location = 'public/images/';

        fs.readFile(temp_path, function(err, data) {
            fs.writeFile(new_location + file_name, data, function(err) {
                fs.unlink(temp_path, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        } else {
                        console.log("success!");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes the same problem facing me several times and according my experience you do't set the content-type in postman header because it should be undefined and node server automatically set the content type according to requirement. If you set the content-type then you do't get any image and other data in the node server .

1. You get the image from the req.body.file
2. you get the other data from req.body
3. app.use(multipart()) in middleware

Procedure how to use multipart as middleware

1. var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
2. global.app = module.exports = express();
3. app.use(multipart());

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Still i didn't get values from "form-data" option.
I mentioned the output for req.body.file and req.body in above question.
please give me a suggestion

Comment: please use the multer as middleware   app.use(multipart()) it will definately work..

Comment: I am new to node js please explain me how to use this
multer as middleware app.use(multipart())

Comment: connect-multiparty is best then multer

Answer (score 3):

I was facing same problem I was not able to get form data fields body parser is not enough to get those values. Hitting google searched a lot of stuff about it but nothing works. Here is the solution how I got form data values.

Note: I am using typescript instead of js

1. Install `multer` package: `npm i multer`
2. Now in `app.ts` or `app.js` import accordingly:

```
import multer from "multer"
```

3. Define the multer function

```
const upload = multer(); // config
```

4. After body parser:

```
app.use(upload.any());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use body-parser for this and also need to update your app.js as

```
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));
```

Comment: i think this will help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-retrieve-post-query-parameters-in-express

Comment: I am already used this code, its not give an output to me.i am not able to get values still from "form-data"

Comment: is the field name in your post man is same as you are using in multer i.e. **recfile**