# SailsJS req.body undefined

Tags: node.js, http, express, request, sails.js

I use REST client apps in chrome to create a request using method POST:
It's here:

```
http://localhost:1337/signup?email=mail@mail.com&password=123123123&password_c=123123123
```

The results (`req.body.email` or `req.body.password`)  return *undefined* when I log them in console 
What's problem? Here is my order in middleware for http request

```
 order: [
            'startRequestTimer',
            'cookieParser',
            'session',
            'myRequestLogger',
            'passportInit',
            'passportSession',
            'bodyParser',
            'handleBodyParserError',
            'compress',
            'methodOverride',
            'poweredBy',
            '$custom',
            'router',
            'www',
            'favicon',
            '404',
            '500'
        ],
```

Thanks all!

Comment: This URL indicate you use GET method, not post.

Comment: restClient Apps allow me to choose a method such as POST or GET

Comment: Try req.params.email instead req.body.email, please.

Comment: I've tried both req.param('email') and req.params.email , but no work :(

Comment: use req.params.all().email and req.params.all().password

Comment: Are you using x-www-form-urlencoded post ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve POST query parameters in Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-retrieve-post-query-parameters-in-express)

Comment: Thanks all, I spent too much time to fix it, so sad. Problem is my post method on client side. I used POSTMAN apps instead RestClient Apps and req.body.email worked  well. (I don't know why the RestClient Apps no work  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.body` doesn't have data, your email and password is in your URL. You can have it by using [`req.params.email`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params).

If this doesn't work, can you post your Controller that handle the route `'POST /signup'`?

Comment: My problem is POST method on client side. Thanks bro!