# Getting no parameters when receiving PayPal IPN

Tags: node.js, http, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am using Node.js for my server and paypal-ipn for IPN verification. When I send an IPN from [the Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/) to myself (my IP + port forwarding), I see **IPN was sent and the handshake was verified.** message on the Simulator page. So my listener is working correctly.

This is my server code:

```
ipn = require('paypal-ipn');
app.post('/ipn', function(req, res){
    res.sendStatus(200);

    ipn.verify(req.params, {'allow_sandbox':false}, function callback(err, msg){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Verify no error.');
            if(params.payment_status == 'Completed') {
                console.log('Payment completed.');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that I don't have the `test_ipn` variable in `req.params`. How I know that? I have intentionally set `allow_sandbox` to `false`.This is a chunk of the code from `paypal-ipn`:

```
if (params.test_ipn && !settings.allow_sandbox) {
    process.nextTick(function () {
        callback(new Error('Received request with test_ipn parameter while sandbox is disabled'));
    });
    return;
}
```

If `allow_sandbox` is disabled (which it is) and I have `test_ipn` set, I should be seeing **Received request with test_ipn parameter while sandbox is disabled**, but I don't. This means the other part of the condition is not met - `test_ipn` is missing. I see this instead:

```
Error: IPN Verification status: <HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;paypal&#46;com&#47;cgi&#45;bin&#47;webscr" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;8d5e6cc1&#46;1462971151&#46;3d758294
</BODY>
</HTML>

    at IncomingMessage.response_end (C:\Users\Hristiyan\Desktop\StickGame\node_modules\paypal-ipn\lib\paypal-ipn.js:57:18)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:926:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Notice that it attempts to use the live paypal URL, not the sandbox one.

With `allow_sandbox` set to true, I get the same thing. That's because `paypal-ipn` receives a request without `test_ipn` set and thinks the IPN is real when it is not.

I also tried to add `test_ipn` to the request myself, but then, I have manually altered the initial request, which makes the transaction invalid and shows this:

```
Error: IPN Verification status: INVALID
    at IncomingMessage.response_end (C:\Users\Hristiyan\Desktop\StickGame\node_modules\paypal-ipn\lib\paypal-ipn.js:57:18)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:926:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

On my PayPal sandbox accounts, I have **Review test payments before they're completed.** set to **On**.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that not only the `test_ipn` parameter was missing, but all of the other ones regarding the payment as well. When I did `console.log(req.params)`, I got an empty object `{}`.

What I had to do was to add `body-parser` which... parses the request body, makes things work and puts the actual IPN parameters in `req.body`. Once I added that, the transactions became verified.

Here's the code:

```
ipn = require('paypal-ipn');
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
})); 
app.post('/ipn', function(req, res){
    var params = req.body;

    res.sendStatus(200);

    ipn.verify(params, {'allow_sandbox':true}, function callback(err, msg){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Verify no error.');
            if(params.payment_status == 'Completed') {
                console.log('Payment completed.');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Nowhere was mentioned that you need to parse the request. At least I didn't see it anywhere.
Make sure that you install the `body-parser` first with `npm install body-parser` or `npm install body-parser --save` (to put `body-parser` in your `package.json` dependencies).

Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-retrieve-post-query-parameters-in-express?rq=1) for more information.

Comment: I was looking for the answer for this for like... days. Thank you