# jQuery Post node being sent to Node JS body using POST

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but when I do an AJAX call using jQuery the 
Node Express App doesn't get values passed to it. the output of the console log is "{}"

I tried curl and curl works just not jQuery request.

curl command:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:3000/upsert -d'{"test":"test"}'
```

**Node JS excerpt**

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));

app.post('/upsert',function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

**JQuery excerpt:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/upsert',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: function () {
        var payload = {};
        payload["name"] = $("#exercise").val();
        payload["reps"] = $("#reps").val();
        payload["weight"] = $("#weight").val();
        payload["date"] = $("#date").val();
        payload["units"] = $('input[name=units]:checked').val();

        return JSON.stringify(payload);
    },
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    failure: function (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-retrieve-post-query-parameters-in-express

Comment: It's not the same issue. I did see that link before I started this. I'm not sending data through forms but through json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're sending **application/json**, you will need the `bodyParser.json()` middleware:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: or he can send it without JSON.stringify ...i think :P

Comment: It probably doesn't matter either way, jquery may automatically `JSON.stringify()` it if it's not a string.

Comment: yup yup make sense.. ty