# Retrieve response of PUT request

Tags: node.js

I am using NodeJS to send a PUT request to a private API that I have access to. When using curl the API sends back JSON and everything works great, but when using NodeJS it isn't sending back anything. I am very new to this and I know my code isn't the best, but it works (other than this one problem). I am wondering how to display the JSON that I should be retrieving back from the the PUT request in the terminal.

NodeJS Server Code:

```
app.post('/myaction', function(req, res) {
    var data = req.body.service;
    var data1 = req.body.serviceId;
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data1);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/services.html');
    myURL = 'http://privateAPI.com/service_instance/' + data1;
    console.log(myURL)
request({
    method: 'PUT',
    uri: myURL,
    multipart: [{
       'content-type':'application/json',
        body: data 
    }]
    }, function(error, request, body){
    })
});
```

When I `console.log(body)` I get the HTML of the API.
When I `console.log(request)` I get the JSON I am sending to the API.
When I `console.log(error)` I get Null.

Links I've read but didn't help:
[How to retrieve POST query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-retrieve-post-query-parameters-in-express?rq=1)
[How to retrieve POST query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-retrieve-post-query-parameters-in-express?rq=1)

Comment: The callback you provide to `request` receives `error`, and `body`, both of which may be helpful in determining what is going on

Comment: I've `console.logg`ed all of them I will edit question and post their responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need to use multipart.

But the problem is that you need to set the content type you expected from the API.

```
request({
    method: 'PUT',
    uri: myURL,
    headers: {
      'accept': 'application/json',
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    multipart: [{
       'content-type':'application/json',
        body: data 
    }]
    }, function(error, response, body){
       console.log(response);
    })
```

Without multipart

```
request({
    method: 'PUT',
    uri: myURL,
    headers: {
      'accept': 'application/json',
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: data,
    json: true
    }, function(error, response, body){
       console.log(response);
    })
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I have just tested this code and I have received no errors, but nothing comes up in the terminal? Is there anyway to `console.log` it so I can see the header?

Comment: @CtrlAltDelete I updated my answer. You have `response` and can see headers, etc.

Comment: @CtrlAltDelete You said "nothing comes up". You mean `body` has nothing?

Comment: When I said nothing comes up, I was not `console.log(body)`. I wasn't console.logging anything in fact. I did the `console.log(response)` and it returns JSON but not the JSON that I want to be returned. When using curl it returns a specific JSON back, and the JSON that the `res` is sending back does not contain it. Thanks again!
Edit:
It also returns the HTML of the API in a very unstructured form

Comment: @CtrlAltDelete There should be in `response.body` or `body`. This is the routine. If this doesn't work, please remove multipart

Comment: What should I put in place of multipart?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122335/discussion-between-ctrlaltdelete-and-ebrahim-pasbani).