# Unable to access query string parameters in a post request using express

Tags: node.js, rest, express, body-parser

I am trying to get query parameters through a POST request and it doesn't seem to receive them.

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

```
app.post('/pubs/:id/submit', function (req, res, next) {

    console.log("query: " + JSON.stringify(req.query)) //prints {}
```

I have tried sending the request through Postman and curl and the request is properly formed.

Comment: What version of Express are you using? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-retrieve-post-query-parameters-in-express

Comment: version 4.14.0 @ztech

Answer (score 0):

> Use body-parser to parse the body.

```
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
```

### Example#1 by parameters

```
POST http://localhost:3000/hello/id/123/access_token/1234556ccc/name/hola
```

`console.log(JSON.stringify(req.params))`

### Example#2 by query

`POST http://localhost:3000/hello?text=abc&access_token=1234556ccc&name=hola`

```
`console.log(JSON.stringify(req.query))`
```

Comment: That only prints out query: {"id":"21421123"}

Comment: As I see in your post you just passed `id`

Comment: I submit the full url with ?accessToken=fet

Comment: I just updated answer in both ways. Please have a look