# Pass data from reactjs to nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to pass data from react js to nodejs. Can anyone help,
Reactjs code -

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:8081/getdata',      
  type: 'POST',
  data: {ajaxid:4},
  success: function(data) {
    this.setState({EmpCollection: data.EmpCollection}); 
  }.bind(this),
  error: function(xhr, status, err) {
    console.error(this.props.Empnumber, status, err.toString());
  }.bind(this)

});
```

Nodejs code-

```
app.get('/getdata', function (req, res) {
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var client = new Client();
 var messageData =  "";
 console.log("req="+req);
  client.get("some URL", function (data, response) {            
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");      
  res.send(data);
});
})
```

How can i get ajaxid:4 in nodejs code?

Comment: can you please add more information. What are you exactly trying?

Comment: I have react js code as above and want to pass ajaxid:4 or any other parameter to node js. how can i get the parameter to notde js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the express plugin body-parser to access the POST data.

You can find more info how to do it here: [How to retrieve POST query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-retrieve-post-query-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

I have found one mistake in your code.

you are calling ajax call with POST method but in server side route is enable for GET method.

```
app.get('/getdata', function (req, res) {
```

replace with

```
app.post('/getdata', function (req, res) {
```

and try

If it is GET request then you can get by using req object. like req.params or req.param('ajaxid')

If it is POST request then you have you use middleware like body-parser and then you can access req.body.ajaxid

Comment: Yeah tried above but problem is how can i extract ajaxid=4 in node js?

Comment: If it is GET request then you can get by using req object. like req.params or req.param('ajaxid')

Comment: If it is POST request then you have you use middleware like body-parser and then you can access req.body.ajaxid.

Comment: added body parser through npm but getting req.body= undefined

Comment: There you need to configure body-parser with server config. Are you using express js?

Comment: yes... with express i am trying to achieve. also i have added the below lines but still not able to achieve..

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
// create application/json parser
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
//Store Api call
app.post('/getdata', function (req, res) {
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var client = new Client();
var messageData =  "";
if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400)
  console.log("Welocme="+req.body.ajaxid);

Comment: Please try with below format                                                                   var express    = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body) // populated!
  next();
})