# How to receive (and decode) JSON from post data in Node.Js Express?

Tags: json, node.js, express, post

Suppose I have sent data with the following code:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/save/" + #{key},
            data: transitions2,
            success: function (data) {

            },
            dataType: "json"
        });
```

where `transitions2` is hierarchical JS object.

Now how can I receive it intact at server side

```
router.post('/save/:key', function(req, res) {
    // where is my data here?    
});
```

**UPDATE**

I found info about body parsers, and found that my site template already contained them. Particularly, `app.js` contains:

```
...
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
...
// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/data', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../data')));

app.use('/', index);
...
```

So I wrote in my `index.js`:

```
...
router.post('/save/:key', function(req, res) {
    var transitions = req.body;
    image_data.save_transitions(req.params.key, req.query.postfix, transitions);
});
...
```

Unfortunately, `transitions` contains

[image]

while on client side it contained

[image]

i.e. was full of data.

What can be the problem?

**UPDATE 2**

I tried to do

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/save/" + #{key},
            data: JSON.stringify(transitions2),
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
```

and I see in `Fiddler2` now, that full Json is passed.

```
[{"start_image":"20170402_1_NATURAL_COL0R","end_image":"20170409_1_NATURAL_COL0R","transition_classes":["no_transition","some_activity"]},...
```

Unfortunately, on server side I observe truncated and corrupted string

[image]

(equal sign should not be in JSON).

And JSON.parse fails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve POST query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-retrieve-post-query-parameters)

Comment: @dan didn't work with body parsers though

Comment: Have you tried stringifying your JSON before you send it? i.e. replace `data: transitions2` with `data: JSON.stringify(transitions2)`.

Comment: @dan yes just tried an failed

Comment: @dan see my update pls

Answer (score 3):

use body-parser middleware to retrieve the data.

```
npm install body-parser
```

configure this in express app.

Find below the sample code

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Then in your router use the following:

```
 router.post('/save/:key', function(req, res) {
        var data = req.body // here is your data   
    });
```

Comment: Yes, I found this, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was on client side only. Correc way to post complex object with json is:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/save/" + #{key},
            data: JSON.stringify(transitions2),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
```

`stringify` and `contentType` are obligatory.

Answer (score 0):

front:

```
axios.post('/attack', {
        number:number,
        count:count
        }, 
        {
            headers:{contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

back:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/attack', (req, res) => {
    let data = req.body
    console.log(data)
    res.send('200')
})
```

console log: `{ number: '(number)', count: '(count)' }`