# Sending data from javascript/html page to Express NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, send

I'm working on a cordova application, using html5 and javascript.

The architecture is the following one : the phone application requests something to the server, which asks a firebird database. The database answers to the server which gives the asked data to the phone application (in html5 / javascript).

I've been able to send the data from the server to the phone with JSON, and I thought it would be the same to send some data from the phone app to the server. However, I have no idea how to send data to such a server from the phone. I've tried to simplify the problem as much as possible.

So considering the following javascript code :

```
var send = { "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null };
var sendString = JSON.stringify(send);
alert(sendString);
xhttp.send(sendString);
```

(the alert does send me : {"name":"John","age":30,"car":null} )

How do I retrieve it in my Node JS server ? For the moment, my code is the following one :

```
app.post('/createEmp', function(req, res){  
    //res.send(req.body.name);
    //console.log('test :' + req.app.post('name'));
    //console.log(req);
    console.log('createEmp');
    if(typeof(req) == 'undefined') {console.log('Y a rien'); } 
    else {
            console.log('La req n est pas vide, son type est : ' + typeof req);
    }    
    console.log(typeof req.query.name);
});
```

I let the comments so that you know what I already tried (there are more)...
Each time, the type of req is either defined or it is an object, but since it is circular I can't parse it so I'm not sure it is the data sent from the phone application.

So could you please give me a piece of advice, an explication about how I could send the data from the phone to the server ?
(I guess I could try to show the data in a url that would be parsed by the server but I prefer not having to do so to protect the data...).

Any help would be appreciated ! Thank you very much !

(PS : I've already been looking for some answers everywhere but nothing worked yet)

Comment: i think you should use socket.io. So you can create socket between phone and server. Then just send data(s) using sockets. It will has more performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Zaphiel, I will do some research about this :)

Comment: you can use websocket connection between phone and server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`req` is an object full of stuff that comes with every request. You need to get body of your request. This might help you: [How to retrieve POST query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-retrieve-post-query-parameters)

But because there's not much client-side JavaScript i ust ask: **Have you specified you want to POST this?**

Try do it like here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send 
...and when you use xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json") you probably don't need to stringify this.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but when I ask :   console.log(req.body.name); , it still returns 'undefined' :/.

Comment: And when I asked to show JSON.stringify(req.body), it returns an empty body : {}.

Comment: I have added some info about content-type header and POST method from MDN above. Try this one.

Comment: Thank you !! We solved this with a friend after a while and it was exactly this " setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")  " that was necessary ! Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all on the client side do this..

```
var send = { "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null };
var sendString = JSON.stringify(send);
alert(sendString);
xhttp.send(send);
```

Then on the server side you need to add a middleware that will populate the body parameter in your request object.

```
var express=require("express");
var bodyParser=require("body-parser");

var app=express();

// Process application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

// Process application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/createEmp', function(req, res){  
//now req.body will be populated with the object you sent
console.log(req.body.name); //prints john
});
```

Comment: I assume you mean: `var send = { "name":"John"...
xhttp.send(sendString);` as opposed to `xhttp.send(send)`?