# Is there a way to parse a form's POST request other than using the original "action" attribute on form elements?

Tags: javascript, forms, express, axios

I was fiddling with ExpressJS last night and found that given a simple code:

```
app.post('/contact', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('Congrats you have submitted the form');
});
```

I am able to respond to it correctly from the server side and actually send a blank document with the text "Congrats you have submitted the form".

However when I remove the "action" attribute and try to handle it with a javascript to perform a POST request like for example using the axios module it doesn't work:

```
axios.post('/contact', { data: { username: <user entered data>, password: { <user entered password> }});
```

I am not able to grab that data from the server side (inside express)

```
app.post('/contact', function(req, res, next) {
  const username = res.data.username;
  const password = res.data.password;
  res.send('Login details: ' + username + ' / ' + password);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your axios code shoulod look like this:

```js
axios.post('/contact', {username: 'user', password: 'pass'}).then(response => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

As for express code, you can find a good explanation in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12008719/3877000