# how to pass data to node.js back-end using jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am trying to create a "follow button" using jquery and node.js
My front-end is like this:

```
<a id="author" href="#"><%= showPost.username %></a> //this displays a username
<p id="follower"><%= currentUser.username %></p> //this displays the current logged in username
<button style="width:100px;" type="button" id="fbtn">Follow</button>
```

jquery is like this:

```
$("#fbtn").click(function(){ 
    var fbtn = $('#fbtn');
    var follower_name=$('#follower').text();
    var followee_name = $('#author').text();
    fbtn.text('Unfollow');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/follow',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'application/json',
            data:JSON.stringify({follower_name:follower_name,followee_name:followee_name}),
            success: function(data){ 
                console.log("success");
            console.log(data);
            }
        });
});
```

back-end is like this:

```
app.post("/follow", function(req, res){
    var followee = req.body.followee_name;

    console.log("Followed");
    console.log(followee);
    res.send("Worked!!!")
});
```

currently I am using console.log so that I can see if the data is passing or not. However, I am getting "**undefined**" in the console. I also got rid of req.body and I get the same log.

I am also getting this in the browser console:

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
```

After I get the data from jquery I will insert it to mySQL database. But I don't know how to pass the data to the back-end.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-retrieve-post-query-parameters

Comment: @JJJ This is what I am currently doing, I am trying to use an ajax method here but it's still passing "undefined" for some reason.

Comment: Did you use bodyparser package in your backend file?...

Comment: Hi @RohitKumar I managed to pass the date, check my answer. I am currently getting a timeout error (504) for some reason even though the button is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake
I changed

```
data:JSON.stringify({follower_name:follower_name,followee_name:followee_name})
```

To:

```
data:{follower_name:follower_name,followee_name:followee_name}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add quotation marks to the property keys of your JSON being passed to the backend.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean exactly? like this: data:JSON.stringify({,followee_name:"followee_name"}) isn't that going to pass it as a string? I tried it and it also shows as undefined? is there an npm package that I am missing?