# bodyparse text data in express

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to get data sent by postman row->text data but fail to get.
I am able to print complete body but how do i print body param?
body is in the form of query string.
[image]

**NodeCode:**

```
   const bodyParser = require("body-parser"); 
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
            extended: true
    }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.text());
    app.post('/data/UploadLogsToServer', async (req, res) => {
            return res.json(req.body);
    });
```

above code prints complete body like
[image]

But How do i fetch only Store parameter from query string ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve POST query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-retrieve-post-query-parameters)

Comment: @DavinTryon, I already tried above solution, it is based on json

Comment: Is there a reason why it has to be plain text? Using JSON would make solving this totally trivial.

Comment: @JunedAnsari you tried `bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })`?  Because your body looks to be in a query string format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

querystring npm module resolved my problem

**Solution:**

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
app.post('/data/UploadLogsToServer', async (req, res) => {
        var q = querystring.parse(req.body);
        return res.json(q.Store);
});
```