# how to bind "this" when passing a React prop into axios.post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, axios, react-props

I am using the `react-paypal-express-checkout` element. There is a method for passing functions on successful payment. In this method, I want to make an `axios.post` where in I pass data to a server.

The data is in the state of the parent component, and is passed like so:

```
<Pay value={this.state.value} />
```

My `axios.post` in the child (`<Pay />`) element is:

```
export default class Pay extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const onSuccess = payment => {
      axios.post(
        "http://localhost:3000/updateValue", {this.props.value}
      );
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <PaypalExpressBtn
          onSuccess={onSuccess}  
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The error given for `this.props.value` is that `this` is a reserved word. I assume that `this` is not bound properly, but I don't know how to do it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `{this.props.value}` is an invalidly formatted javascript object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't related to function binding. `onSuccess` is an arrow, it cannot and shouldn't be bound. `{this.props.value}` is incorrect syntax for object literal.

In case `value` contains data that should be posted, it should be:

```
  axios.post(
    "http://localhost:3000/updateValue", {data: this.props.value}
  );
```

Comment: Thank you, I see what happened.

Follow up question if you have a moment...

How will should my server receive this new value? If you could even give me some key words I will do the research, just think I am not asking google correctly. Thanks!!!

Comment: `/updateValue` API endpoint should receive it as *POST parameters*, likely in JSON format. In case you're using Express, it's something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-retrieve-post-query-parameters