# how to bind an HTML form and a nodejs code

Tags: html, node.js, forms

I want guidance to find a solution to my problem in the development of my application. I want to reuse the content of the input tag that is present my form created in another code of Node.js

**For Example:** If I enter the keyword *nodejs* in the input tag of my form "index.html".

I want to reuse this keyword *nodejs* in the following line

```
app.search('Query', 5, function(error, result)
```

and instead of the word *Query* I want this line to receive the new keyword *nodejs* and on every time I enter a new keyword in the form it will be taken into consideration in my nodejs file "search.js".

I do not know how to bind an `HTML` form and a `nodejs` code

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Your question is too broad at the moment. How are you processing requests in Node.js at the moment? Are you using any framework, such as Express? What does the form look like? Are you making a standard GET request? Is the search term appearing in the URL?

Comment: Why are you using a POST form for a search? This is the sort of thing GET is designed for.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-retrieve-post-query-parameters

Comment: yes i use express as framework and mongodb as database, Thesearch term didn't appear in the URL    and my form is like this:  <form method = "POST" action = "/ search" id = "formId">
        <label> <input type = "text" name = "query"> </ label>
       
        <input type = "submit" value = "Search">
    </ Form>  @Quentin