# Cant access the data in a post request. Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I'm trying to access the data in a POST request however when I console.log(req.body) I'm just getting an empty {}.

I feel like my error is somewhere in the markup?

Here is the relevant client side markup

```
<div id='create' class="card">
  <form method = 'post' action='/'>
    <textarea placeholder="Enter your name"></textarea><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

relevant backend code

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/',(req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);

});
```

If the user enters "John" in the textarea I'd like the page to refresh and the name John to appear in the terminal.

I plan to export that data to another file that is connected to my mongodb

Comment: you have a space in your assignment: `method = 'post'`. I am not sure if that is allowed...

Comment: textarea needs a name in order to assign it as part of the payload.  Give that a shot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve POST query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-retrieve-post-query-parameters)

Comment: @Fallenreaper it was this thank you very much

Comment: @Heyrio Ill add an answer then if that is the case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When looking at your console log statement you are dumping the resource which was an empty object.  Given that information, I looked at your HTML.

When dealing with forms in HTML, you will have a form tag, but the inputs, textarea etc inside of the form will need a *name* attribute in order to build the payload correctly.

```
<textarea name="test"></textarea>
```

will simply show a new property in the request payload called *test* which contains the contents for what is in the textarea at the time the form was submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You're telling bodyParser to parse the body as if it's JSON. However, a standard `<form>` will submit data not as JSON, but as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

To read that in your express app, you'll instead need something like this:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

---

#### Allowing both JSON and form data

If you want to allow both URL encoded and JSON data, you can combine both methods:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

A full example can be [found here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#expressconnect-top-level-generic).

---

#### Built-in alternative

Good to note: if you're using a [recent version](https://expressjs.com/en/changelog/4x.html#4.16.0) of Express, you can also exchange the `body-parser` module for a built in alternative:

```js
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(express.json())
```

This still uses `body-parser` underneath (and therefore has the exact same synax), but might look slightly neater in your app.

Comment: body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option app.js:9:20

I've added that and when I do and run it I get this in the terminal.

I'd also like to add that on client page when I hit the submit but the page will continually load and say waiting for localhost.

Answer (score -1):

This problem has been solved by a combination of two things.

1.) I needed to add app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())
because it was not sent by the form as if it were JSON data.

2.) I needed to add a name to the textarea.