# req.query in Express.js is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments, mern

I am implementing `Stripe Checkout` in a MERN application.

After a customer makes a successful payment, he/she is redirected to a checkout success URL where `CheckoutSuccess` page renders on the screen. Also, Stripe sends a `session_id` in the URL, as shown in the picture below.
[image]

When `CheckoutSuccess` page renders, I send a `POST` request to `/api/order/success`. In the route handler function, I need to access the `session-id`(which is in the URL) sent by Stripe.

The problem I am facing is when I try to console.log `req.query`, I get a blank object; therefore `req.query.session_id` returns `undefined`.
[image]

Why is `req.query` a blank object?

The code snippets are as follows:
orderRoutes.js

```
const express = require("express");
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

const router = express.Router();

router.post(
  "/success",
  asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query);
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(
      req.query.session_id
    );
    const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(session.customer);
    res.send(customer);
  })
);

module.exports = router;
```

orderSlice.js

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

const initialState = {
  status: "idle",
  customer: null,
  error: null,
};

export const fetchCustomer = createAsyncThunk(
  "order/fetchCustomer",
  async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post("/api/order/success");
      return data;
    } catch (err) {
      return rejectWithValue(err.response.data);
    }
  }
);

export const orderSlice = createSlice({
  name: "order",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchCustomer.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "loading";
    },
    [fetchCustomer.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "succeeded";
      state.customer = action.payload;
    },
    [fetchCustomer.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "failed";
      state.error = action.payload.message;
    },
  },
});

export default orderSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: You need to append the querystring to the url using `'/api/order/success' + location.search`

Comment: if you use method POST,  you shuld use `req.body` because `req.query` is used when the method is GET .

Comment: @Gleny I don't think so.

Comment: @Molda The query string is already there in the URL, returned by Stripe. Why do I need to append it?

Comment: @hks what does your fetch() request look like? The one you make to `/api/order/success`?

Comment: @HKS Gleny is correct, use `req.body` rather than `req.query` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-access-post-form-fields

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access POST form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-access-post-form-fields)

Comment: @hmunoz Added in the question. I am using Redux Toolkit.

Comment: your `fetch()` call isn't passing any data or query params, right? that seems to be the issue here

Comment: @NicoNekoru Even when I change the method to `GET`, `req.query` is still a blank object. Why so?

Comment: Have you tried specifying a specific query parser with `app.set()`?

Comment: @hmunoz You were right. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving out of comment and into an answer

your fetch() call isn't passing any data or query params, right? that seems to be the issue here