# getting "Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')" in my POST request

Tags: javascript, html, express, handlebars.js

My POST request isn't working and it's not updating? The error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')
```

```js
app.post('/create-user', function(req, resp) { 
          const client = new MongoClient(uri);
          const dbo = client.db("eggyDB"); // Get the database object
          const collName = dbo.collection("users"); // Get the collection
    
          const info = {
              username: req.body.username,
              password: req.body.password
          };
    
          collName.insertOne(info)
              .then(function() {
                  console.log('User created');
                  resp.render("main", {
                    layout: "homepage",
                    title: "My Home page"
                  });
              })
              .catch(function(err) {
                  console.error('Error creating user:', err);
                  resp.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
              })
      });
```

this is my html code (in the partials folder):

```html
<form
    name="signup"
    action="/create-user"
    method="POST"
    class="popup-signup-content"
    onsubmit="return verifyPassword()"
    >
    <h1 onclick="closeSignup()" id="close-login" type="submit">x</h1>
    <img src="/images/LOGO-YL.png" alt="None" />
    <input
        id="username-signup"
        name="username"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter Username/Email"
        required
    />
    <input
        id="password-signup"
        type="password"
        placeholder="Enter Password"
        required
    />
    <input
        id="verify-password-signup"
        name="password"
        type="password"
        placeholder="Re-Enter Password"
        required
    />
    <button class="login-button bold" type="submit" onclick="console.log('Form Submitted')">Register</button>
</form>
```

it won't add a new user to the database but it connects to the database. it also won't show the onclick function when Register is pressed. what should i do?

i tried asking chatgpt but i think it was slowly drifting me away from the solution. what do you think should i do here?

Comment: `req.body` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the case is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12008719/7196495)

Try:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded( {extended: true} )); 

app.post('/create-user', function(req, resp) { 
          const client = new MongoClient(uri);
          const dbo = client.db("eggyDB"); // Get the database object
          const collName = dbo.collection("users"); // Get the collection
    
          const info = {
              username: req.body.username,
              password: req.body.password
          };
    
          collName.insertOne(info)
              .then(function() {
                  console.log('User created');
                  resp.render("main", {
                    layout: "homepage",
                    title: "My Home page"
                  });
              })
              .catch(function(err) {
                  console.error('Error creating user:', err);
                  resp.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
              })
      });
```

Comment: okay i added app.use(express.urlencoded( {extended: true} )); but when i tried printing out the values of req.body.username and req.body.password it's blank. do you know how to fix that problem? thank you!

Comment: @Nawsh could you console.log(req.body) pls?

Comment: it outputs an empty array {}

Comment: sorry it outputs { username: '', password: '' }

Comment: it seems form sends proper fields but without values. Maybe they are overwrittend during form send. How does verifyPassword function looks like?