# How do I get request parameters URLs with Node.js

Tags: url, node.js, request, query-string, httprequest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get GET (query string) variables in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-node-js)

I am very new to Node.js and am trying a few simple examples to get familiar with what it can do. I am trying to pull values from a request's query string but can seem to find how it's done. I had a look at a querystring module but it seems to be more for serializing objects to query strings. Is there a native function for parsing a query string?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6912872/844726

Comment: Yep sorry I'll close now... Thx