# node.js equivalent of $_server['query_string']

Tags: php, node.js

What is node.js equivalent of

```
    $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

and also to put it in:

```
    list($a,$b,$c ...) = explode('/', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? Node's API docs are relatively short and easy to read.

Comment: Do you just want the query string?  If so, just ask that. Phrasing your question in the context of another programing language (php in this case) severely limits the pool of people who can answer your question.

Comment: Can't remember the exact object property, but it is a direct descendent of the `request` object. A `console.log` will bring it up.

Answer (score -1):

See the answer here for how to get the query string: [How to get GET (query string) variables in Express.js on Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-node-js)

Then use querystring.parse() to get an object representing the keys and values in the query string.

http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq_options