# How to access the GET parameters after "?" in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, query-string

I know how to get the params for queries like this:

```
app.get('/sample/:id', routes.sample);
```

In this case, I can use `req.params.id` to get the parameter (e.g. `2` in `/sample/2`).

However, for url like `/sample/2?color=red`, how can I access the variable `color`?

I tried `req.params.color` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1038, accepted):

So, after checking out the [express reference](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query), I found that `req.query.color` would return me the value I'm looking for.

req.params refers to items with a ':' in the URL and req.query refers to items associated with the '?'

Example:

```
GET /something?color1=red&color2=blue
```

Then in express, the handler:

```
app.get('/something', (req, res) => {
    req.query.color1 === 'red'  // true
    req.query.color2 === 'blue' // true
})
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to validate "id" ?

Comment: @AnandRaj: what do you mean with: how to validate "id"? What kind of validation do you want? BTW, you can get the value of `id` in your function like this: `var sampleId = req.params.id;`.

Comment: Use `req.params.whatever` in latest versions.

Comment: Mind that `req.params` is different from `req.query`! http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query @adelriosantiago

Comment: I don't believe this answer (from the OP) actually answers his own original question!  He clearly asked how to access a querystring value IN COMBINATION WITH A POSITIONAL PARAMETER (:id).  I have exactly the same issue, and this answer does NOT provide a solution ?!

Answer (score 99):

Use req.query, for getting the value in query string parameter in the route.
Refer to [req.query](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query).
Say if in a route, http://localhost:3000/?name=satyam you want to get value for name parameter, then your 'Get' route handler will go like this

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.query.name);
    res.send('Response send to client::'+req.query.name);
});
```

Comment: perhaps some info about  querystring to get a complete answer

Answer (score 82):

Query string and parameters are different.

You need to use both in single routing url

Please check below example may be useful for you.

```
app.get('/sample/:id', function(req, res) {

 var id = req.params.id; //or use req.param('id')

  ................

});
```

Get the link to pass your second segment is your id example: http://localhost:port/sample/123

If you facing problem please use Passing variables as query string using '?' operator

```
  app.get('/sample', function(req, res) {

     var id = req.query.id; 

      ................

    });
```

Get link your like this example: http://localhost:port/sample?id=123

Both in a single example

```
app.get('/sample/:id', function(req, res) {

 var id = req.params.id; //or use req.param('id')
 var id2 = req.query.id; 
  ................

});
```

Get link example: http://localhost:port/sample/123?id=123

Answer (score 75):

**Update:** `req.param()` is now deprecated, so going forward do not use this answer.

---

Your answer is the preferred way to do it, however I thought I'd point out that you can also access url, post, and route parameters all with [`req.param(parameterName, defaultValue)`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.param).

In your case:

```
var color = req.param('color');
```

From the express guide:

> lookup is performed in the following order:
>
> - req.params
> - req.body
> - req.query

Note the guide does state the following:

> Direct access to req.body, req.params, and req.query should be
>   favoured for clarity - unless you truly accept input from each object.

However in practice I've actually found `req.param()` to be clear enough and makes certain types of refactoring easier.

Answer (score 49):

@Zugwait's answer is correct. `req.param()` is deprecated. You should use `req.params`, `req.query` or `req.body`.

But just to make it clearer:

`req.params` will be populated with only the route values. That is, if you have a route like `/users/:id`, you can access the `id` either in `req.params.id` or `req.params['id']`.

`req.query` and `req.body` will be populated with *all* params, regardless of whether or not they are in the route. Of course, parameters in the query string will be available in `req.query` and parameters in a post body will be available in `req.body`.

So, answering your questions, as `color` is not in the route, you should be able to get it using `req.query.color` or `req.query['color']`.

Answer (score 18):

The express manual says that you should use [req.query](http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#req.query) to access the QueryString.

```js
// Requesting /display/post?size=small
app.get('/display/post', function(req, res, next) {

  var isSmall = req.query.size === 'small'; // > true
  // ...

});
```

Answer (score 7):

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const { usersNdJobs, userByJob, addUser , addUserToCompany } = require ('./db/db.js')

const app = express()
app.set('view engine', 'pug')
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  usersNdJobs()
    .then((users) => {
      res.render('users', { users })
    })
    .catch(console.error)
})

app.get('/api/company/users', (req, res) => {
  const companyname = req.query.companyName
  console.log(companyname)
  userByJob(companyname)
    .then((users) => {
      res.render('job', { users })
    }).catch(console.error)
})

app.post('/api/users/add', (req, res) => {
  const userName = req.body.userName
  const jobName = req.body.jobName
  console.log("user name = "+userName+", job name : "+jobName)
  addUser(userName, jobName)
    .then((result) => {
      res.status(200).json(result)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(404).json({ 'message': error.toString() })
    })
})
app.post('/users/add', (request, response) => {
  const { userName, job } = request.body
  addTeam(userName, job)
  .then((user) => {
    response.status(200).json({
      "userName": user.name,
      "city": user.job
    })
  .catch((err) => {
    request.status(400).json({"message": err})
  })
})

app.post('/api/user/company/add', (req, res) => {
  const userName = req.body.userName
  const companyName = req.body.companyName
  console.log(userName, companyName)
  addUserToCompany(userName, companyName)
  .then((result) => {
    res.json(result)
  })
  .catch(console.error)
})

app.get('/api/company/user', (req, res) => {
 const companyname = req.query.companyName
 console.log(companyname)
 userByJob(companyname)
 .then((users) => {
   res.render('jobs', { users })
 })
})

app.listen(3000, () =>
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 6):

you can simply use `req.query` for get query parameter:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let color1 = req.query.color1
    let color2 = req.query.color2
})
```

The `url` module provides utilities for URL resolution and parsing. URL parse without using Express:

```
const url = require('url');
const queryString = require('querystring');

let rawUrl = 'https://stackoverflow.com/?page=2&size=3';

let parsedUrl = url.parse(rawUrl);
let parse = queryString.parse(parsedUrl.query);

// parse = { page: '2', size: '3' }
```

Another way:

```
const url = require('url');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const queryObject = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
});
```

`url.parse(req.url,true).query` returns `{ color1: 'red', color2: 'green' }.`
`url.parse(req.url,true).host` returns `'localhost:8080'.`
`url.parse(req.url,true).search` returns '?color1=red&color2=green'.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the `app.get`:

```
app.get('/some/page/here', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query.color) // Your color value will be displayed
})
```

You can see it on expressjs.com documentation api:
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Answer (score 3):

A nice technique i've started using with some of my apps on express is to create an object which merges the query, params, and body fields of express's request object.

```
//./express-data.js
const _ = require("lodash");

class ExpressData {

    /*
    * @param {Object} req - express request object
    */
    constructor (req) {

        //Merge all data passed by the client in the request
        this.props = _.merge(req.body, req.params, req.query);
     }

}

module.exports = ExpressData;
```

Then in your controller body, or anywhere else in scope of the express request chain, you can use something like below:

```
//./some-controller.js

const ExpressData = require("./express-data.js");
const router = require("express").Router();


router.get("/:some_id", (req, res) => {

    let props = new ExpressData(req).props;

    //Given the request "/592363122?foo=bar&hello=world"
    //the below would log out 
    // {
    //   some_id: 592363122,
    //   foo: 'bar',
    //   hello: 'world'
    // }
    console.log(props);

    return res.json(props);
});
```

This makes it nice and handy to just "delve" into all of the "custom data" a user may have sent up with their request.

**Note**

Why the 'props' field? Because that was a cut-down snippet, I use this technique in a number of my APIs, I also store authentication / authorisation data onto this object, example below.

```
/*
 * @param {Object} req - Request response object
*/
class ExpressData {

    /*
    * @param {Object} req - express request object
    */
    constructor (req) {

        //Merge all data passed by the client in the request
        this.props = _.merge(req.body, req.params, req.query);

        //Store reference to the user
        this.user = req.user || null;

        //API connected devices (Mobile app..) will send x-client header with requests, web context is implied.
        //This is used to determine how the user is connecting to the API 
        this.client = (req.headers) ? (req.headers["x-client"] || (req.client || "web")) : "web";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably a bad idea because it makes it harder to maintain your endpoints. You no longer know which method clients will be using to pass parameters.

Comment: That is actually one of the main advantages of this approach to be honest, not having to know where the fields come from. The ExpressData class above acts as a bridge, allowing you to modularise your business logic, moving it away from the express controller routes, i.e. you're not baking 'req.query', 'req.body' into your code, this also makes your business code easily testable, completely outside of express.