# Access GET parameter

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I want to send my `server.js` (in an AngularJS controller) an set the `id` parameter like this:

```
 $http
    .get('/getCst', {
        params: {               
            id: customerID
        }
     })
     .success(function (data,status) {
          $scope.customer = data
     });
```

But i'm not sure if this is the correct way and what to write in the Node.js `server.js`:

```
app.get('/getCst', function (req, res) {

        console.log(//how do i get the id sent by the client?);     
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get GET (query string) variables in Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-node-js)

Comment: its not a duplicate. my url looks like `127.0.0.1:8080/cust/534543`
534543 is the id. I cant get it with req.query.id

Comment: What does `/cust/534543` have to do with `/getCst`? Your AngularJS code will *not* make a GET request to `/cust/534543`, not evetn to `/getCst/534524`. It will call `/getCst?id=534534`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Use `req.query.id`. Ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007997/how-to-access-the-get-parameters-in-express-js-or-node-js

Answer (score 3):

It's my solution

```
app.get('/getCst/:id', function (req, res, next) {

        var id = req.params.id;    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
app.get('/getCst:id', function (req, res) {

        console.log(req.param('id'));     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

app.get('/getCst', function (req, res) {

```
    var id = req.query.id;
```

});