# How do i search in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using mongoosastic and it's working fine but the problem that I'm facing is that, how do I take the object from `.post` method and pass it to `.get` method?

For example:

```
router.post('/search', function(req, res, next) {
   Product.search({ something: 'Something'}, function(err, result) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.redirect('/search') // <--- How do i pass the result object?
   });
});

router.get('/search', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('search');
});
```

I tried another approached where I use `req.flash`, but I don't really like that approach.

How did you guys solve this problem? it's a really basic search, where user search then it will redirect that user to another page where it either will show the found result or not found.

Comment: why don't you have a function that processes it? (meaning both the get function and the post function would call a common function) why do you need to pass it to the get function? Is this backend code or front end code, it looks like express?

Comment: req.search = result; ? Then in your get('/search'), you can access req.search. It's the basic middleware approach. Think of middleware like a sequence of filter that processes your request, adding, removing, modifying data on the way. That's what you want to do ? Add the search result to the request ?

Comment: why do you want to do that? you can serve the request in the `post`.

Comment: @SoluableNonagon it is backend , using express.js

Comment: @Ludo, So I need to create a custom middleware?

Comment: No, as @Aᴍɪʀ said you can serve the response in the POST. Instead of res.redirect('/search'), do res.render('search', {search : result}).

Comment: @Ludo, but i if Im not mistaken I need a .get method to serve the page?

Comment: @Amir but i if Im not mistaken I need a .get method to serve the page?

Comment: Only if it's a GET request, you need a router.get . If it's POST, you need a router.post. Please, read on different request types. GET POST PUT MERGE ...

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: @JackMoscovi No you don't. It is perfectly acceptable to serve the request in `.post`.

Comment: One of you guys should write the answer so I could accept it. It does work, but I just don't understand why .post could render a page ..?

Comment: Post is how u accept the request, it makes no different to how u respond to it. Redirecting makes no sense here

Comment: @JackMoscovi I just posted an answer with some more information for you to know. I'd be glad if I can help more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to redirect the user to another route with GET to send the response.

You can serve the request in `.post` and it is perfectly acceptable.

`POST` and `GET` are two forms of HTTP Request. No matter what type of request comes to a web server, the response could be anything. It could be a redirect, or an actual web-page, or other types of things such as errors.

I don't think you need this, but just to be complete, for search pages it could be a different scenario. GET requests could be bookmarked in the browser, because all it takes to re-render the page is the URL. But POST requests could not be, because it needs post parameters as well which is in the request's body. If you want to let the users bookmark the page with the result or have a permanent link to the same page with the result, you could serve the request in GET requests (as well). Adding an extra parameter like `?q=search-term` to the URL for example ...

This is a sort of sending parameters via GET request. A `/search` route will also catch a `/search?q=search-term` URL. You can have access to that using `req.query.q` and its value would be `"search-term"` (look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007997/how-to-access-the-get-parameters-after-in-express) for more info). So you can either modify your form to send a GET request instead of POST (`<form action="get">...`) or you can redirect the user back to the search page using GET and pass the parameter along the URL. And finally serve all the search result in a GET request.

But again, this is more advanced stuff, for what you need to do, generally, it is all good to serve a request whether it is POST or GET or anything else.

Comment: Hey Amir, thank you for explaining in detail, but is it okay if you show some example because currently Im quite confused. I created a github gist https://gist.github.com/anonymous/69802ee3d24ff19f3ee0

Comment: @JackMoscovi the code really depends on your whole project, so do not expect this code work, it is just to give you an idea. [Here](https://gist.github.com/amir-s/70fe3de0092a560468b4).
And if that answers your question, consider up-voting and marking it as the answer for future visitors :)