# Query parameters in express 4 give me a "No default engine was specified" error

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

I am developing a web app using the MEAN stack (no Mongo for now) 
I am trying to pass the name of a file on the server using a query paramerer, the error happens when i get :

*"localhost:8080/api/result?filename=for-debug-file-name"*

**It is working well if I remove the console.log() right below** 
But when I get the query parameter it gets me the "Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided”.

(This route correspond to api/result)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();   

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.query('filename')); // ERROR
    res.status(200).json({ "json-test": 42 });
})

module.exports = router;
```

Here are my angular routes :

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'result',
    component: ResultComponent,
},
{
    path: 'upload',
    component: UploaderComponent,
},
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/upload',
    pathMatch: 'full'
}];
```

And here is my ResultComponent.ts :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getParsedDocumentData('for-debug-file-name');
}

getParsedDocumentData(fileName: string): Observable<string[]> {
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('filename', fileName);
    let options = new RequestOptions({ params: params });

    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/result/', options)
                    .map(res => res.json())
                    .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError (error: any) {
    return Observable.throw(error);
}
```

I would really appreciate your help as I have been stuck for 4 hours.
Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear why you get this message because it usually appears when you do res.render(), i.e. actually use template engine. But I'm not sure why you use query as a function. It should work as req.query.filename. It is possible that req.query() causes an error, and default error handler tries to output error page with res.render().

Comment: Actually using the dot notation returns undefined and i dont know why

Comment: have you connect ```express.Router``` file to ```app``` ? like ```app.use(router-file-required);```

Comment: yes i unfortunately did, actually if I put the string name of the file instead of the query parameters, it works fine

Comment: Well, calling req.query as function when it's not a one definitely won't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the GET parameters after "?" in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007997/how-to-access-the-get-parameters-after-in-express)

Answer (score 0):

`query` method in `request` object does not exists. Instead use `query` property to access `filename` parameter.

```
console.log(req.query.filename);
```

[Reference](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query)

Comment: thanks, i have undefined, and if i log req.query i get {}.

Comment: @HugoBeisser, if you get `{}`  for `req.query`, means, there are no query params at all. Check the request & see if query params are being sent.