# req.params is not a function

Tags: node.js, express

my api url:

```
{{url}}/api/v1/users/updateHome?access_token={{access_token}}
```

I am trying to access the property `access_token`. I have tried the following ways to access it but it returns error:

1. `req.params('access_token'); //returns req.params is not a function`
2. `req.params.access_token; //returns undefined`

Since `req.param('access_token')` which works but now deprecated, how can I access the property `access_token` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the GET parameters after "?" in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007997/how-to-access-the-get-parameters-after-in-express)

Answer (score 3):

Query parameter should be accessed from `req.query`. For instance

`req.query["access_token"]`

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because what you have is a query parameter.

To access it use `req.query`.