# Pass parameter to Express controller from button click

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-applications

Preface: I am writing a Web App using Node.js, Express, and MongoDB.

When a button is clicked I am trying to pass a parameter via URL from my `index.ejs` to the Express controller `ItemController.js` in order to dynamically create a filtered set of data.

The button is defined within `index.ejs` as follows:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="/items/items" onclick="loadItems(value, 'Scripting Languages')">
      Scripting Languages
</button>
```

In my external Javascripts file which houses miscellaneous functions, `loadItems` executes the following:

```
function loadItems(page, subcategory) {
    window.history.replaceState({}, '', "?subcat=" + subcategory); //set URL Param
    $('#mainContent').load(page); //load item listing page into grid within HTML GridLayout
}
```

After this, the router/controller handles the data filtering and page rendering:

**Router (item.js)**

```
...
// Get all items
router.get('/items', item.items);
...
```

**Controller (ItemController.js)**

```
...
  // loads item listings
  itemController.items = function(req, res) {
    Item.find({}).exec(function (err, items) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error:", err);
      }
      else {
        var URLSubcat = "Scripting Languages"; //this variable needs to change
        var filtered = items.filter(function(el) {
          return el.subcategory === URLSubcat;
        });
        res.render("../views/items/items", {items: filtered});
      }
    });
  };
...
```

I have tried using `req.query.subcat` in order to try and grab the parameter from the URL, however it comes back as undefined. I have also tried the techniques in the links below to no avail. What should I be doing to accomplish this? Is there a better way to go about this?

**Previously Tried**

[How to get GET (query string) variables in Express.js on Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js)

[How to access the GET parameters after "?" in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007997/how-to-access-the-get-parameters-after-in-express)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> $('#mainContent').load(page);
> ```

The URL you are requesting is stored in the `page` variable.

> ```
> loadItems(page, subcategory)
> ```

… which is defined as an argument

> ```
> onclick="loadItems(value, 'Scripting Languages')"
> ```

… which is passed from the onclick event handler

> ```
> value="/items/items"
> ```

… which gets it value from that attribute.

---

The query string doesn't show up because the URL you are requesting does not include a query string!

The only query string you have is from here:

> ```
>  window.history.replaceState({}, '', "?subcat=" + subcategory);
> ```

… which modifies the URL in the browser addressbar and history without actually requesting it.

Comment: Oh man, you're totally right! I forgot that `replaceState` only changes the URL in the address bar and not the request itself... Okay, great! So since this is the case, I would have to change the button value to `value="/items/items?subcat=Scripting Languages"`?

Comment: Went through and changed `value` to the above comment, everything works perfectly now. Thanks for your help!