# NodeJS Route GET:/find/123 not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, node-modules

I am trying to create an api which would fetch data from local mongodb

I have added dependencies , created the database schema and the name of the collection, and connected to MongoDB:

```
var cors = require('cors');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var app = express();

var supportSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {type:ObjectId, auto: true },
    UserId: { type:String, required: true },
    Name: String
}, {
    collection: 'abc'
});

var SupportModel = mongoose.model('Model', supportSchema);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dbName');
```

Now added routes in the same .js file that we will use to query the data:

```
app.get('/find/:query', function(req, res) {
    let envId = request.params.envId;
    SupportModel.find({environmentId: envId}, {}, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
})
```

I am getting an error `Route GET:/find/123 not found`

Answer (score 0):

```
let express = require('express');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let cors = require('cors');
let router = express.Router();
let app = express();

let http = require('http');
let server = http.Server(app);

app.use(bodyParser.json());  
use with existing express server.
app.use (cors());
```

Then your app.get() works

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {  } ):
```

You need to use body- parser middle ware to working with router in node.js . Hope this helps you.

Comment: Getting error `{"message":"Route GET:/find/123 not found","error":"Not Found","statusCode":404}`

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007997/how-to-access-the-get-parameters-after-in-express