# JavaScript/MongoDb: useState Problem null values on initial registration

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I'm getting a problem with useState(). The problem is whenever the page refresh userId has no value because I set it but inside my code I acquire it's value.

```
const [userId, setUserId] = useState("");

function registerUser(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        if (isAdmin == "select permission" || isAdmin == null || isAdmin == undefined || isAdmin == "") {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: "warning",
                title: "Error message!",
                text: "Please select a permission to proceed!"
            })
        } else if(department == "select department" || department == null || department == undefined || department == "") {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: "warning",
                title: "Error message!",
                text: "Please select a department to proceed!"
            })
        } else if(position == "select position" || position == null || position == undefined || position == "") {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: "warning",
                title: "Error message!",
                text: "Please select a position to proceed!"
            })
        } else {
            fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/users/email-exist', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                // API only accepts
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email: email
                })
            }).then(res => {
                return res.json()
            }).then(gatheredData => {
                if (gatheredData === false) {

                    fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/users/register',{
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            firstName: firstName,
                            lastName: lastName,
                            department: department,
                            position: position,
                            email: email,
                            mobileNo: mobileNo,
                            isAdmin: isAdmin,
                            password: "password123",
                            departmentId: departmentId
                        })
                      }).then(res => res.json()).then(convertedData => {

                        if(convertedData === true){

                            fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/users/get-id',{
                                method: 'POST',
                                headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                                },
                                body: JSON.stringify({
                                    email: email
                                })
                            }).then(res => res.json()).then(userData => {
                                setUserId("");
                                console.log(userData)
                                setUserId(userData);
                                console.log(departmentId)

                                if(userData === "" || userData === undefined) {
                                    alert("Error")
                                } else {
                                    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/users/enroll/${departmentId}`,{
                                        method: 'POST',
                                        headers: {
                                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                                        },
                                        body: JSON.stringify({
                                            agentId: userId
                                        })
                                    }).then(res => res.json()).then(enrolled => {
                                        console.log(enrolled)
                                        if (enrolled === true) {
                                            Swal.fire({
                                                icon: "success",
                                                title: "Congratulations!",
                                                text: "Account has been created successfully."
                                               })
                                        } else {
                                            Swal.fire({
                                                icon: "success",
                                                title: "Warning!!",
                                                text: "Account has been created but not linked to any departments."
                                               })
                                        }
                                    })
                                }
                            })
                        } else {
                            Swal.fire({
                                icon: "error",
                                title: "Error message!",
                                text: "Something went wrong, please try again later."
                            })
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: "warning",
                        title: "Error message!",
                        text: "Email address has already been used!"
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

What the system does:

1. Create a User
2. Get the Users Id
3. Update Department array to add the User as it's agent.

What is the error that I'm getting:

1. Whenever the page refreshed and create a new user I'm getting error messages with userId and it says the value is null and the registration will pushed through because that's how I designed it and it's id will be displayed in the consoled tab for testing but I'm no longer able to proceed with step 2 and 3.
2. If I don't refresh the page and create a new user again, it's id will be displayed and will proceed with step 2 and 3 but the id that will be stored to my agent's array from the department document is the previous id that was generated from the previous user created.

Please help :-)

Comment: refreshing page actually SHOULD remove all the data react is holding. if u want to persist data in-between refreshes then use sessionStorage.

Comment: Thanks. I understand it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things,

1. Refreshing page actually SHOULD remove all the data react is holding. If u want to persist data in-between refreshes then use sessionStorage
2. Setting a value via useState hook shows the value AFTER a render. So, you cannot do `setUserId` and in the next promise `agentId: userId` and expect to get the updated value. You will get the last value.

So instead of `agentId: userId` do `agentId: userData` that should be a quick fix.

Comment: Got it. That's why I get the same issue on my other page. Really appreciate your help.