# node.js http get request parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I want to handle an HTTP request like this:

```
GET http://1.2.3.4/status?userID=1234
```

But I can't extract the parameter `userID` from it. I am using Express, but it's not helping me. For example, when I write something like the following, it doesn't work:

```
app.get('/status?userID=1234', function(req, res) {
  // ...
})
```

I would like to have possibility to take value `1234` for any local parameter, for example, `user=userID`. How can I do this?

Comment: And specifically on that page: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6913287/95190, which is the answer that best fits your needs.

Comment: Also, you can use `req.param("userID")` if you don't know where the value might be, but `req.query.userID` is all you'd need.

Answer (score 21):

You just parse the request URL with the native module.

```
var url = require('url');
app.get('/status', function(req, res) {
  var parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var query = parts.query;
})
```

You will get something like this:

```
query: { userID: '1234' }
```

**Edit:** Since you're using Express, query strings are automatically parsed.

```
req.query.userID
// returns 1234
```

Comment: Sorry, may be I not understand how it really work but if I have this code

    
    var url = require('url');
    app.get('/status', function(req, res) {
        
         var url = url.parse(request.url, true);
          var query = url.query;
           res.send("response: "+query.useriD);
        });          

and send request

    get http://1.2.3.4/status?userID=1234

I receive answer

     "error": "request is not defined"

Comment: Express has a number of other options that don't require another module (see duplicate answer)

Comment: after change request.url to req.url server give me answer:  "error": "Cannot call method 'parse' of undefined"

Comment: @AlexCebotari - look at the duplicate post suggested in a comment on your question. And my other comments. You don't need `parse`.

Comment: Sorry, the error is due to reassignment of the URL variable since I was in a rush to get to school. And @WiredPrairie, thanks for pointing out that Express already parsed query strings, I had forgotten.