# strip params in Node.js and then add to requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm wondering if this can be done with Node.js and express.js. On my incoming url i have parameters such as.

```
http://localhost:8080/restaurant.html?siteid=7&locationid=8&companyid=7
```

I want to extract the query and then append it to any incoming request

so that when the client code calls for my JSON and my router sends the request to

```
 app.get('/siteinfo.json', function(req, res) {
  console.log(company, site , location);
  getdata_hdlr.get_site_setup(company, site , location);
 });
```

I can pass the query params on to the function being called.

Can this be done or do I need to do this in my client code?

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-node-js?

Comment: [Use req.query](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `req.query` and then save all the data in `req.session`, then use session to extract the data that you need.

Comment: I believe this needs the `express.urlencoded()` middleware in place to parse the query string.