# How to get the redirect url in nodejs

Tags: node.js, redirect

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function JumpSelf() {
        self.location = "/?session=mQOMhYUXNnuM1QcvO1zH";
    }
</script>
<script>
    setTimeout("JumpSelf()", 700);
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

the page will be redirect http://test.com/?session=mQOMhYUXNnuM1QcvO1zH

Comment: What exactly you mean? You have made a page that will keep on reloading. Which redirect URL you want to get?

Comment: yes,i want to get `/?session=mQOMhYUXNnuM1QcvO1zH`

Comment: How's that a problem? you can get the querystring part using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6912872/1520671). also, do a `console.log(request);` to see what all things you can get.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is no standard HTTP redirect.  The only reliable way to determine the end URL is to run something like PhantomJS which will run the web page and all of its JavaScript in-context.