# Get (post/get) value in express from android?

Tags: android, node.js, post, express, get

I have simple app that use express (node) as server and android as client,I want to communicate between android and express over http

i have this code in express

```
var express = require( 'express' );
var http = require( 'http' );

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer( app );

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log( "hello word" );    
});
```

i type in browser(PC) **mydomain.com:8080** to access express and it works fine. I have 2 Question

1. how i can send value use following url and receive in express ?
2. if my question number 1 success,how it work if I access from android?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You could send values in the URL itself, as parameters, like `mydomain.com:8080/some_value`. To get this value in your express app, you have to tell your `/` route that something is comming:

   ```
   app.get('/:your_param', function (req, res) {
     var json = JSON.stringify(req.params); // you get your_param here as a JSON object
     console.log("hello world: " + json);
     res.send(json); // you have to send a response, otherwise, your browser will wait forever...
   });
   ```

   You can sens value in a POST request too, but this post would became too long. Take a look at the [express](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html) docs.
   Other thing that I should point out is since you're using express, you don't need the `http` module. And you have to make your app listen for requests, you must add the line `app.listen(3000);`. Remember that you can choose whatever port you want. In the express docs they show a very simple example:

   ```
   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();

   app.get('/', function(req, res){
     res.send('hello world');
   });

   app.listen(3000);
   ```
2. To access you express app from your Android device, just use the browser, like in your computer.

Comment: thanks, i found that i want in this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-node-js