# getting query parameters in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, query-string

I have a url like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/hi?key=abcd345&section=you
```

I need the value of the parameter, section.
I use:

```
req.query.section
```

But the value is undefined.

I tried testing

```
console.log(req.url);
```

But the output is only:

```
/hi?key=abcd345
```

And I also tried:

```
console.log(req.query);
```

But the output is only:

```
{"key":"abcd345"}
```

I dont know what happened to the parameter section. Am I missing something?
Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-node-js

Comment: But I also tried the answer from that question. I tried: var url = require('url');
var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;

And console.log(query); Still, the only parameter shown is the key.. and there is no section field..

Comment: try req.param("section")

Comment: `req.query` absolutely should work for this. If we can see all the code, maybe we can help.

Comment: Got it. I found out that the problem is in curl. when passing multiple parameters, it need to put single quotes around the url. Thanks for the help guys! Sorry for not mentioning I am using curl..