# How to write a middleware to log the url or the body parameters

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to implement a middle ware that accepts any incoming request and logs all the request parameters, so how can I do that using express?

I tried this code but didn't work,

```
//logger function
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  console.log('%s %s', req.method, req.url);
  next();
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the node docs? BTW http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-node-js

Comment: you'll also need the `body-parser` middleware

Comment: @meanIOstack: No; he's looking for the Express docs.

Comment: Right, so `req.body` will return an object of post data, while `req.params` will return an object of url fields.

Comment: `req.params` will only give you the params in your route. You'll have to parse the url.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have mentioned: [see the document](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use).

I want to warn you another thing:

do not write user's account info(e.g.: email,password) in the log file,it's dangerous!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
  /**
   * This is for logging entrance to a specific route.
   */
  static log(req, _res, next) {
    const {
      body,
      query,
      params,
      method,
      originalUrl,
    } = req;
    let info = `Entered ${method} ${originalUrl} `;
    if (Object.keys(body).length) info += `| body: ${JSON.stringify(body)}`;
    if (Object.keys(query).length) info += `| query: ${JSON.stringify(query)}`;
    if (Object.keys(params).length) info += `| params: ${JSON.stringify(params)}`;
    Logger.info(info);
    return next();
  }
```

and implement it on the route:

```
testRoute.get('/test', log, TestController.Test);
```

You can user if for all POST/PUT/GET/DELETE