# URL parameters Node.js Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, express, parameters

How do i get the parameters supplied in a URL in node using express? So far iv'e tried using body-parser middlewear, but it either doesn't support this type of parsing or i haven't found the right documentation. any help would be much appreciated!

example request : http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/something?var1=321&var2=123

so essentially my question is how do i access var1 and var2 when the server receives this URL

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-node-js

Comment: That's called the _querystring_.

Comment: The Express answer you're looking for:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6913287/362536

Comment: oh i did not know this was already asked :O my apologize.