# In Node.js, assignment of variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

In `app.js` I have hard-coded 3 keywords:

```js
var a = 'family';
var b ='friends';
var c ='teacher';
```

and saved them in an array called 'List'

```js
var List = [a, b, c];
```

Now I passed this List in track (Twitter API)

```js
twit.stream('statuses/filter', { track: List }, function(stream) {
    stream.on('data', function (data) {
        // code
    });
});
```

Now, I want to accept the user's keywords, so in `index.html` I am providing 3 textboxes (i.e. `<input type="text">`)

When the user enters the first keyword in textbox 1 it should be assigned to `var a` of `app.js`, when the 2nd keyword is inserted it should be assigned to `var b`, and so on.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        Key 1<input id="Key_1" class="" name="" type="text" placeholder="First key" required /><br><br>
        Key 2<input id="Key_2" class="" name="" type="text" placeholder="Second key" required /><br><br>
        Key 3<input id="Key_3" class="" name="" type="text" placeholder="Third key" required /><br><br>

        <button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You could do something similar from this question: [How to get GET (query string) variables in Express.js on Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-on-node-js)

So when submitting the form, you could get the query parameters. But first, you'd need to give each input a name, lets say `a`, `b` and `c`:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">

Key 1<input id="Key_1" class="" name="a" type="text" placeholder="First key" required /><br><br>
Key 2<input id="Key_2" class="" name="b" type="text" placeholder="Second key" required /><br><br>
Key 3<input id="Key_3" class="" name="c" type="text" placeholder="Third key" required /><br><br>

<button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you would need to make your HTML form post the data somewhere in your Node app and get the request values using this:

```
app.post('/post', function(req, res){
  a = req.query.a;
  b = req.query.b;
  c = req.query.c;
});
```