# Javascript variables for Get http

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, get

I am learning JavaScript and would like to do the JavaScript equivalent of PHP's `$_GET[Var] = $foo;` I am coding a basic CDN type server for a project, 
also, how can I serve a file for download with JavaScript? The plan is to run this code inside  a NodeJS node. Sorry if I explained this badly, I am terrible at explaining things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get GET (query string) variables in Express.js on Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

To serve existing files from your Node.js app, use `express` with `express.static`: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Example below uses ECMAScript 2015 elements and assumes Node.js 4 or 5 with static files stored in `public` directory:

```
const http = require('http'); 
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));

const server = http.createServer(app).listen(8080, serverCallback);

function serverCallback() {
  const host = server.address().address;
  const port = server.address().port;
  console.log(`Server listening on ${host}:${port}`);
}
```

Comment: with javascript is it possible to serve a file for download, if its name matches the get request in the url?

Comment: @alextix With Node.js yes.  The code above does exactly that.

Comment: this will help. var http = require('http');

Comment: @alextix Thanks.  Fixed.

Comment: It was not the answer to the question, that is just a simple web server.