# Get and javascript? like php's if $_GET[foo]

Tags: javascript, node.js, get

I am coding a javascript http web server node, for a CDN project, I am used to PHP's

```
if ($_GET = "hello"); echo "Yey!"
```

but have no idea how to do so, I am new to javascript.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559227/javascript-variables-for-get-http?

Comment: the earlier question was answered, but the answer was off topic, the code I was given was for a node.JS web server.

Comment: @alextix, check my answer

Answer (score 0):

**NodeJS**

```
var url = require('url');
var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;
```

> Without NodeJS:
>   Use URI.js to get the query string.
>   https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/

```
var uri = URI("urn:uuid:c5542ab6-3d96-403e-8e6b-b8bb52f48d9a?hello=world");
uri.protocol() == "urn";
uri.path() == "uuid:c5542ab6-3d96-403e-8e6b-b8bb52f48d9a";
uri.query() == "hello=world";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this functions:

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

However, synchronous requests are discouraged, so you might want to use this instead:

```
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

> Notes: Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 / SeaMonkey 2.27), **synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated** due to the negative effects to the user experience.

Comment: How would I do a simple variable comparison? like ===

Comment: in javascript i think it is like this == or ===