# how to access query string with Node.js

Tags: html, node.js, query-string

I am new to Node.js.
I have written simple Node.js program to print hello world.
and it works fine.

Now when I passes the querystring along with that then it gives an error

Node.js

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

   // Send the HTTP header 
   // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
   // Content Type: text/plain
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

   // Send the response body as "Hello World"
   response.end('Hello World\n'+request.q);
}).listen(8081);

// Console will print the message
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
```

Query from Browser

```
http://127.0.0.1:8081/?q=MrX
```

It Gives

```
Hello World
undefined
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you

```
    var http = require("http");
    url = require("url"); 
http.createServer(function (request, response) {

   // Send the HTTP header 
   // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
   // Content Type: text/plain
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

   // Send the response body as "Hello World"
    var _get = url.parse(request.url, true).query; 
    response.end('Here is your data: ' + _get['data']); 
//   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8081);

// Console will print the message
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
```

URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:8081/?data=MrX
```