# Is there some way to pass a parameter to a router in express nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I got two files my main file

file `app.js`

```
var products_id = require('./routes/productId');
app.use('/allProducts/:id',products_id);
```

and my route file `productId.js``where I am making a request :

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {}
```

which I want to access to the parameter that the user pass /allProducts/:id/

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent Router? http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try moving the parameter placeholder out of `app.use('/allProducts/:id')` (within app.js) and into your router definition (within productId.js).

With that done you'll have:
`app.use('/allProducts', products_id)` in `app.js` 
and `router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next){...})` in `productId.js`.

Then you should have access via `req.params.id`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly and you wamt to get the parameters on the server passed through express,  see here:

[How to get GET (query string) variables in Express.js on Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the req object when you enter this route

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
  console.log(req.query.id);
});
```

You'll find what you want from here :)

Comment: Already tried and also with req.params.id both undefined they are empty