# Is there any way to get http requested token continuously?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need a php/javascript/jquery suggestion that will give the  requested token value continuously. 
Like *http://IP/mar/request.php?token="something"* after sometime it will change to *http://IP/mar/request.php?token="NewSomething"*

I want to get requested token value continuously when anyone request this.

Comment: Explain `continuously` ?

Comment: Like a service that will check is there any http request.

Comment: I have found my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js    It gives what i exactly want. It is done by Nodejs. But i need it in web based script like php/javascript/jquery. Please help me.