# How should I extract value from Url in Node Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I recently started programming on nodeJs.

I am using Angular JS, resource to call API's as

```
demoApp.factory('class', function ($resource) {
      return $resource('/class/:classId', { classId: '@_classId' }, {
        update: { method: 'PUT' }
      });
    });
```

And in Controller, I have delete method as;

```
   // The class object, e {classId: 1, className: "Pro"}

$scope.deleteClass = function (class) {
        var deleteObj = new Class();
        deleteObj.classId = class.classId;
        deleteObj.$delete({classId : deleteObj.classId}, function() {
            growl.success("Class deleted successfully.");
            $location.path('/'); 
            },function () {
                growl.error("Error while deleting Class.");
            }
        ); 
    };
```

Using browser, I verified call goes to :

```
http://localhost:3000/class/1
```

Now in node Js, How should I extract value from Url,

In server.js

```
app.use('/class', classController.getApi);
```

In classController.js

```
exports.getApi = function(req, resp){
    switch(req.method) {
        case 'DELETE':
            if (req) {
                // how to extract 1 from url.
            }
            else {
                httpMsgs.show404(req, resp);
            }
            break;
```

I have tried ,

```
console.log(req.params);
console.log(req.query);
```

But no luck.

I am seeing

```
    console.log(req._parsedUrl);
query: null,
pathname: '/class/1',
path: '/class/1',
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Using req.url.replace("/", ""); i am able to extract 1.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a get call right ? You can use angular $http service, with method as get. Replace your app.use('/class') with app.get('/class', function). Then you can use req.param('classId') to retrieve data. I think it should work.

Try updating your app.use to app.use('/class/:classId'), then try req.params.classId

Comment: Thanks but That's the delete call, Does not make sense if I change to get.

Comment: Sorry I missed it. try updating your app.use to app.use('/class/:classId'), then try req.params.classId.

Comment: No, If I change like that it will effect my whole design of calling CURD API.

Answer (score 0):

Try using req.hostname as in:

`http://host/path'

Comment: console.log(req.hostname); provides localhost.

Comment: Which value are you trying to get? There are no query string parameters, hence why query: null.

Comment: Do I need to parse ? Does we have any method on nodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js).

Tldr;

```
var url = require('url');
var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;
```

Also read the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstring_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) on node url.

Comment: As I  said, it does not have query or param, request is as
localhost:3000/class/1. So query or param function does not work.